# Até que ponto devo seguir as convenções, onde posso aplicar específicos padrões de estilo próprio?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome, convenções

Até que ponto devo seguir as convenções nos códigos Java, isto é, até onde o convenção é uma regra?

Posso desenvolver e aplicar meus próprios estilos de padrões de codificação no meu código, sabendo que vou utilizar esse padrão por todo o mesmo?

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de negativarem essa pergunta. Acho ela completamente válida e foi colocada de uma maneira bem interessante. "Até onde a convenção é uma regra?". Quem negativou pode se manifestar aqui?

Comment: Convenção não é regra.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Na verdade, o que é regra mesmo é o que é imposto pelo compilador, o resto é convenção.

Há na prática duas convenções vigentes. Em especial, a comunidade do Eclipse tende a ter um padrão de formatação diferente do pessoal da Oracle (que herdou o estilo da Sun). Muitos grupos tendem a seguir o formato do Eclipse ou da Oracle, com alguns grupos menores misturando-os ou então adotando convenções que divergem de ambos em algumas partes. Na maioria dos casos, tal como onde colocar ou não espaços ao redor de operadores, casts, métodos, parênteses, declarações de generics, índices de arrays, etc, o estilo costuma ser uniforme. As maiores divergências são quanto ao `{`, quanto a identação e quanto ao `switch`.

## Getters e setters

Existem muitos frameworks que deduzem quais são as propriedades dos seus objetos ao olhar para os métodos getters e setters. Se você utilizar uma convenção diferente nesse ponto, os frameworks não vão encontrar as suas propriedades ou manipulá-las corretamente, e daí neste caso você acaba sendo obrigado a seguir as convenções.

Os getters devem ter o nome começando por `get` seguido de uma letra maiúscula, ter o retorno diferente de `void` e não ter parâmetros. Se o tipo de retorno for `boolean` (o tipo primitivo), o prefixo pode ser tanto `get` quanto `is`. Alguns frameworks (mas nem todos) permitem que o prefixo `is` possa ser usado também quando o tipo de retorno é `Boolean` (a classe empacotadora).

Os setters devem ter o nome começando por `set` seguido de uma letra maiúscula, ter exatamente um parâmetro, e ter retorno `void`. Alguns (mas nem todos) os frameworks permitem que o retorno possa ser do tipo da própria classe que declara o método. Além disso, na maioria dos casos, o tipo do parâmetro do setter deve ser o mesmo que o retorno do getter.

## Identificadores

Quanto ao resto, a rigor você normalmente é livre para usar do jeito que você quiser, desde que o compilador aceite. Entretanto, ainda assim vale a pena utilizar as convenções. Um dos motivos é a coloração de sintaxe, tal como no código abaixo:

```
class Classe1 { // A palavra Classe1 vai ficar azulada.
}

class classe2 { // A palavra classe2 vai ficar preta.
}

int teste; // A palavra teste vai ficar preta.
int TESTE; // A palavra TESTE vai ficar preta.
int Teste; // A palavra Teste vai ficar azulada.
```

Observe a diferença de cores. A ideia é que no caso acima, nomes de classes sejam azulados enquanto que os demais identificadores pretos. Entretanto, se você não seguir as convenções da linguagem, o StackOverflow vai dar a coloração errada para as palavras. Acontece que esse não é um problema exclusivo do StackOverflow e vários outros programas vão ter o mesmo problema.

E a saber a convenção de nomenclatura de identificadores é a seguinte:

- Nomes de classes, interfaces, `enum`s e construtores devem ter a inicial de cada palavra maiúscula, com as demais letras minúsculas. As palavras não são separadas. É permitido o uso de números. Por exemplo: `StringBuilder`, `JPanel`, `Consumer`, `NullPointerException`, `LayoutManager2`.
- Nomes de métodos, variáveis locais, variáveis de instância, variáveis estáticas que não sejam constantes, parâmetros de métodos, parâmetros de lambdas e pacotes devem ter a primeira letra minúscula, com a inicial de cada uma das palavras que não a primeira maiúscula e todas as demais letras também minúsculas. Por exemplo, `toString`, `getClass`, `isVisible`, `setEnabled`, `clone`, `element`, `start`, `getX1`, `temp`, `x`, `y`, `f1`, etc.
- Nomes de pacotes e módulos (Java 9+) devem seguir o padrão de domínio reverso e ter todas as letras minúsculas sem separação entre palavras. Números são permitidos. Por exemplo, `java.lang.annotation`, `javax.swing`, `javax.validation.constraintvalidation`, `org.json`, `org.apache.commons.lang3`, `org.springframework.web.servlet`, `java.base`, `android.service.quicksettings`. Os nomes começando com `java`, `javax` e `javafx` são ou deveriam ser restritos a JDK e os demais idealmente devem seguir o padrão de domínio reverso (mas nem sempre isso ocorre na prática, a exemplo do android). Após a parte do nome do pacote que corresponde ao domínio, a lógica usada ao dividir os pacotes em subpacotes é a lógica de organização do projeto e não a lógica de organização da nomenclatura do projeto. Ou seja, você deve usar `com.example.meuprojeto.bancodedados` ao invés de `com.example.meu.projeto.banco.de.dados`.
- Nomes de constantes (ou seja, objetos imutáveis declarados com `static` e `final`) e elementos de `enum`s devem ter todas as letras maiúsculas com palavras separadas por `_`. Números são permitidos. Por exemplo, `SOUTH_EAST`, `TOP`, `TIMED_WAITING`, `DECIMAL_FLOAT`.
- Parâmetros de tipos genéricos são denotados por uma única letra maiúscula, tal como `Map<K, V>` ou `List<E>`.

Também há alguns frameworks que, tal como ocorre com getters e setters, exigem que o nome dos métodos tenham uma determinada estrutura. Isso era até que bastante comum antes das anotações serem introduzidas no Java 5, onde ferramentas como o JUnit 3 exigiam que métodos de teste tivessem o nome prefixado com `test` e o EJB 2 também tinha várias regras de nomenclatura. Com o advento das anotações, essas restrições de nomes no método (consideradas irritantes) acabaram sendo progressivamente abolidas (tal como no JUnit 4 e no EJB 3), mas de vez em quando há um ou outro framework que ainda faz algum tipo de imposição.

## Espaçamento em geral

Quanto ao espaçamento, o problema é bem menor, mas a legibilidade ainda assim pode ser afetada, e portanto essa questão também é importante.

Há regras básicas tais como:

- Nunca colocar espaços antes de vírgula ou de ponto-e-vírgula, mas sempre colocar depois.
- Sempre colocar espaços ao redor de operadores binários, mas não ao redor de operadores unários.
- Não colocar espaço imediatamente após `(`, `{` ou `[`.
- Nunca colocar espaços dentro dos tipos (possivelmente genéricos), exceto após a vírgula que estiver dentro de uma lista de parâmetros genéricos. Ou seja, `List<Map<String, Thread>>` e `double[]` estão ok, enquanto que `List <Map< String , Thread> >` ou `double []` não estão.
- Colocar espaço logo após o cast. Ou seja, `int x = (int) y` está ok, enquanto que `int x = (int)y` não.
- Nunca colocar espaços imediatamente antes de quebras-de-linhas (são invisíveis e inúteis e só servem para criar conflitos de versão em ferramentas como Git e SVN).
- Mais um monte de outros detalhezinhos.

## O local do `{`

Há uma divergência quanto ao lugar onde colocar o `{` do início da classe, interface, método, `if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, `do...while`, `synchronized`, `try`, `catch` ou `finally`. Essa divergência existe desde a época em que o C estava iniciando. Há essencialmente dois estilos em uso:

- Colocar o `{` no final da linha do bloco que ele está abrindo - Esse é o estilo que a Sun adotou e que a Oracle seguiu. Esse estilo foi criado por Brian Kernighan e Dennis Ritchie, criadores do C, sendo também adotado por Bjarne Stroustrup que criou o C++ e por Linus Torvalds que criou o kernel do Linux. Exemplo:

  ```
  if (x) {
      // blablabla
  }
  ```
- Colocar o isoladamente `{` em uma linha somente para si. Esse padrão foi iniciado por Eric Allman que criou o BSD Unix em C, sendo fortemente influenciado pelo padrão vigente do Pascal, que utiliza as palavras-chaves `begin` e `end` para delimitar blocos, sendo o `begin` normalmente colocado isolado em sua própria linha. No Java, esse é o padrão adotado pela comunidade Eclipse. Exemplo:

  ```
  if (x)
  {
      // blablabla
  }
  ```

Há outras formas também de se decidir onde o `{` é colocado e algumas variantes em determinados casos especiais. Essa divergência já ocasionou alguns longos debates e flamewars em listas de e-mails e fóruns da internet (e [obviamente ele também existiu no escopo do StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2715/43532)). Eu pessoalmente sigo o estilo adotado pela Oracle, com um pequeno porém: na declaração de métodos e construtores, quando a lista de parâmetros é grande e acaba sendo dividida em várias linhas, eu utilizo o `{` em sua própria linha para ele ficar evidenciado, ao invés de apenas ficar pendurado na linha do último parâmetro.

## Largura máxima de uma linha

Esse ponto também pode ser controverso. A maior parte das convenções dita que 80 ou 79 colunas é o limite.

Entretanto, esse limite advém dos antigos terminais e consoles e das antigas impressoras dos anos 1980 e anteriores que tinham um limite de 80 colunas na tela/papel. Hoje em dia esse limite já está mais que superado.

Além disso, Java é uma linguagem de programação bastante verbosa, e por causa disso, é muito fácil e costumeiro acabar-se por ultrapassar a octogésima coluna. Forçar o limite de 80 colunas pode deixar várias instruções e expressões divididas em um número tão grande de linhas (ainda mais se tiverem vários níveis de identação) que deixará o código significativamente mais difícil de ser lido e compreendido.

Assim sendo, eu considero que um limite de 120 a 160 colunas é o ideal. Não dou um número específico, pois acho que isso depende muito de preferências pessoais e particularidades de cada projeto e qualquer número que eu desse seria apenas opinião pessoal minha.

## Tamanho da identação

Essa daqui é a maior de todas as divergências e a maior causadora de flamewars e brigas acerca de estilos na internet.

Há duas questões envolvidas aqui. A primeira é se a identação é com tabs ou com espaços. A segunda é que se os espaços forem escolhidos, quantos serão esses espaços.

Primeiramente, seja lá qual for o critério de identação que você escolher, você deverá ser consistente. Identar algumas linhas ora com tabs e ora com espaços é o pior dos mundos. Pior ainda quando uma mesma linha mistura tabs e espaços na identação. Se for usar espaços, use sempre a mesma quantidade de espaços para representar uma identação, caso contrário ficará horrível e inconsistente.

Comunidades em C, C++ e outras linguagens têm uma míriade de partidos diferentes, cada qual com seu nicho e com suas disputas em relação aos demais partidos. No Java, essencialmente há apenas dois partidos: Identar com 4 espaços ou identar com 1 tab. A Sun originalmente recomendava qualquer uma das duas formas e a comunidade do Eclipse adotou a segunda. Posteriormente (por volta da época do Java 5, eu acho), a Sun mudou de ideia e padronizou para si e passou a recomendar a primeira forma apenas (4 espaços).

Na minha opinião pessoal, a identação com espaços é melhor, pois:

- Em teoria, o código identado com tab deveria funcionar com qualquer tamanho de tabulação a ser adotado pelo usuário que lê o código, de forma que a escolha do tamanho exato caberia a este. Na prática porém, apenas o exato tamanho utilizado por quem escreveu o código originalmente irá funcionar e se dois ou mais desenvolvedores alteraram partes diferentes de um mesmo código usando tamanhos de tabulação diferentes, ele vai ficar errado de qualquer jeito, independente do tamanho de tabulação utilizado.
- Ao usar espaços, o código que eu escrevi será visualizado pelo meu vizinho exatamente da forma como eu visualizo. Da mesma forma, o código que meu vizinho escreveu será visualizado por mim exatamente da forma como ele visualiza.
- Ter que ficar configurando tamanho de tabulação em cada editor para cada código diferente que eu encontro por aí a fora é um porre.
- Muitos softwares, incluindo clientes de e-mails e navegadores da web não permitem facilmente que o tamanho do tab seja configurado (a maioria considera que um tab são 8 espaços, alguns consideram que são 4). Esses softwares também não têm como adivinhar qual é o tamanho de tab que seria mais adequado em cada situação.
- Ter que se atentar com a largura do tab é algo que o usuário que está apenas navegando ocasionalmente em uma página ou lendo e-mails em listas de discussões não deveria ter que se preocupar.
- Respeitar a largura máxima de uma linha é bem mais difícil quando se usa tabs ao invés de espaços, vez que o meu tamanho de tab pode ser diferente do tamanho do tab do meu vizinho.
- Se você recebe uma mensagem de erro dizendo que algo na coluna 33 da linha 82 está errado, e essa linha está identada com tabs, descobrir qual exatamente é a coluna 33 nessa linha pode ser algo um pouco difícil.

Na prática, muitas comunidades em diversas linguagens de programação estão muito lentamente abandonando os tabs e adotando a identação apenas por espaços. A Sun mesmo, acabou por fazê-lo pelos motivos descritos acima. As convenções de identação do Python 3 também contra-indicam tabs e os aceitam apenas para manter compatibilidade com código escrito em versões anteriores.

Este processo de migração de tabs para espaços por aí a fora é bem lento (demorando décadas) porque há muita gente por aí que não abre mão de usar tabs, simplesmente odeia identar com espaços e há muitos softwares por aí que usam o tab como forma padrão de identar. Esse é o debate e o ponto de discordância mais acirrado em questão de convenções de escrita de código.

## Os `case`s do `switch`

Esse daqui também é um ponto de discordância, embora seja bem menor do que os três anteriores. Na prática há duas convenções competindo entre si. São elas:

1. Colocar os `case`s e o `default` no mesmo nível de identação do `switch`:

   ```
   switch (x) {
   case 1:
       // Blablabla
   case 2:
       // Blablabla
   default:
       // Blablabla
   }
   ```
2. Colocar os `case`s e o `default` com um nível de identação a mais que o `switch`:

   ```
   switch (x) {
       case 1:
           // Blablabla
       case 2:
           // Blablabla
       default:
           // Blablabla
   }
   ```

## O `}` antes do `else`, do `catch` e do `finally`

Esse daqui é um detalhe bobo, mas há três diferentes estilos:

1. ```
   if (x)
   {
       // blabla
   }
   else
   {
       // blabla
   }

   try
   {
       // blabla
   }
   catch (AlgumaException x)
   {
       // blabla
   }
   finally
   {
       // blabla
   }
   ```
2. ```
   if (x) {
       // blabla
   } else {
       // blabla
   }

   try {
       // blabla
   } catch (AlgumaException x) {
       // blabla
   } finally {
       // blabla
   }
   ```
3. ```
   if (x) {
       // blabla
   }
   else {
       // blabla
   }

   try {
       // blabla
   }
   catch (AlgumaException x) {
       // blabla
   }
   finally {
       // blabla
   }
   ```

As pessoas que usam `{` em sua própria linha quase sempre adotam o primeiro estilo.

Aqueles que usam `{` junto com a declaração do bloco que está sendo aberto tendem a adotar o segundo estilo, mas em alguns casos podem preferir o terceiro.

## Variáveis do tipo array

Há duas formas em Java igualmente válidas de se declarar um array:

1. ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   ```
2. ```
   public static void main(String args[])
   ```

Em geral a primeira forma é considerada superior, pois nela você segue o padrão *[tipo da variável + nome da variável]* que se aplica a todas as outras formas de declarar variáveis na linguagem. Já a segunda forma é bem menos legível, e está presente apenas porque foi herdada do C e do C++, pois nela você declara primeiro uma parte do tipo da variável, seguida do nome da variável e seguida da parte restante do tipo, e neste caso a informação sobre o tipo da variável fica espalhada em dois locais distintos desnecessariamente.

## Alinhamento de parâmetros em múltiplas linhas

Esse daqui é um tanto polêmico e diz respeito ao posicionamento dos parâmetros de métodos e construtores, quando estes são muito numerosos. Considere pois os seguintes casos:

1. ```
   public String metodo(
           int x,
           int y,
           int z);
   ```
2. ```
   public String metodo(int x,
                        int y,
                        int z);
   ```

As duas formas são encontradas por aí a fora, mas eu pessoalmente sou a favor apenas da primeira pelos seguintes motivos:

- A primeira forma mantém o mesmo padrão de identação de todo o resto do código, e não faz com que nenhuma linha acabe sendo identada por uma quantidade de espaços que não seja múltipla do tamanho da tabulação.
- A segunda forma é frágil, pois se você decidir alterar o nome do método, ou o tipo de retorno ou algo referente aos modificadores `static`, `public`, `protected`, `private`, `strictfp`, `abstract`, `final`, `default` ou `native`, vai ter que se preocupar em não bagunçar com o alinhamento dos parâmetros.
- Se a segunda forma for feita identando-se com tabs, o resultado será um desastre. Frequentemente, será necessário misturar-se espaços e tabs na identação, pois o tamanho da identação nas linhas dos parâmetros pode não ser múltipla do tamanho do tab. Além disso, apenas um determinado tamanho da tabulação específico vai produzir a identação adequada, e a ideia de que qualquer tamanho de tabulação serviria vai para o beleléu.

Na primeira forma acima, normalmente a identação dada aos parâmetros em relação a declaração do nome do método é dupla. O motivo disso é para que fique em um nível de identação diferente tanto do corpo do método como da declaração em si. Por exemplo:

```
public String meuMetodo(
        int parametro1,    // Dois níveis de identação além do cabeçalho.
        int parametero2)
{
    return "abc";          // Um nível de identação além do cabeçalho.
}
```

## Chaves após `if`, `else`, `while` e `for`

O uso de chaves (`{}`) após o `if`, `else`, `while` ou `for` é opcional em Java caso o corpo seja uma única instrução (característica essa herdada do C e do C++). Na verdade, isso ocorre porque o corpo desses blocos é definido como sendo uma instrução solitária ou um conjunto de instruções delimitado por chaves.

Observe as duas formas a seguir:

1. ```
   if (x) {
       fazerAlgumaCoisa();
   } else {
       fazerOutraCoisa();
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       System.out.println(i);
   }
   ```
2. ```
   if (x)
       fazerAlgumaCoisa();
   else
       fazerOutraCoisa();

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       System.out.println(i);
   ```

As duas formas são equivalentes, e há quem goste da segunda forma. Eu sou fortemente contrário a segunda forma porque ela é muito propensa a descuidos acidentais:

```
if (x)
    fazerAlgumaCoisa();
    fazerOutraCoisa();

estamosForaDoIf();
```

Observe que neste caso a identação engana e faz parecer com que a chamada ao método `fazerOutraCoisa();` está dentro do `if`, quando na verdade está fora. Muitas vezes isso acaba fazendo com que o programador acabe por enganar a si mesmo e a escrever código com bugs, o que poderia ser prevenido ao sempre adotar-se as chaves nos blocos `if`, `else`, `for` e `while`.

Outro caso desastroso:

```
if (x)
    //estamosDentroDoIf();

estamosForaDoIf();
```

No caso acima, ao comentar a linha dentro do `if`, a linha seguinte que estava fora do `if` acabou sorrateiramente entrando dentro dele!

Mais outro caso:

```
if (x)
    if (y)
        System.out.println("x e y são verdadeiros.");
else
    System.out.println("x é falso.");
```

Observe que o `else` parece estar no `if` de fora, mas na verdade está no `if` de dentro e o código não vai fazer o que o programador acha que faria.

Há uma exceção apenas que acho que vale não colocar as chaves no `if` (mas isso é opinião pessoal minha). Que é quando o `if` não tem `else` e está em uma única linha:

```
if (x) fazerAlgumaCoisa();
estamosForaDoIf();
```

Os blocos `try`, `catch`, `finally`, `switch`, `do...while` e `synchronized` não sofrem com este problema porque as chaves são obrigatórias neles.

## Identação de linhas comentadas

Uma outra diferença entre a convenção usada pela Sun/Oracle e pela Eclipse concerne na identação de linhas comentadas.

- Estilo Sun/Oracle:

  ```
  public class X {
      public void x() {
          // Esta linha é um comentário.
          int x = 5;
          // x++;
      }
  }
  ```
- Estilo Eclipse:

  ```
  public class X {
      public void x() {
  //      Esta linha é um comentário.
          int x = 5;
  //      x++;
      }
  }
  ```

Eu pessoalmente, detesto o estilo do Eclipse, pois os espaços entre o `//` e o texto não são mais uma identação conforme ela é definida (espaços no começo da linha), e se a identação for feita com tabs, resultará em tabs no meio da linha ao invés de apenas no começo, o que é horrível. Além disso, um leitor desatento pode não notar que a linha do `x++;` está comentada, ainda mais se houver muitos níveis de identação e o editor utilizado não tiver coloração de sintaxe ou tiver uma que seja inadequada.

## Outros

Há outros conceitos a se considerar também tais como:

- Quebras-de-linha devem ser colocadas antes ou depois de operadores binários em expressões lógicas ou matemáticas muito longas? A ideia de colocar antes é a que está prevalescendo por deixar claro que a linha em questão é continuação da anterior.
- Onde quebrar linhas em chamadas a métodos com muitos parâmetros complexos?
- Qual é melhor forma de ordenar os atributos, métodos, construtores e classes internas dentro de uma determinada classe?
- Qual é a ordem das anotações a serem aplicada a classes, atributos, métodos e construtores?
- Quais são as melhores formas de dar bons nomes a classes, métodos, atributos, parâmetros e variáveis locais, evitando que nomes que fiquem demasiadamente longos ao mesmo tempo que sejam suficientemente descritivos e compreensíveis?
- Codificar tudo em inglês ou usar identificadores com nomes em português (ou alguma outra língua diferente)? Casos que levem a identificadores que misturam duas diferentes línguas são aceitáveis? Se quiser tudo em inglês, será que os programadores do projeto são bem fluentes em inglês?
- Colocar uma quebra-de-linha no final do arquivo ou não?
- Onde colocar linhas em branco dentro do código de algum método?
- As quebras-de-linha do código-fonte devem ser `\r` (Mac), `\n` (Unix/Linux) ou `\r\n` (Windows)?
- A codificação de caracteres a ser usada deve ser UTF-8 ou ISO-8859-1? UTF-8 tem se mostrado cada vez mais vantajoso nesta disputa devido a melhor padronização, menor probabilidade de surpresas desagradáveis com encodings e possibilidade de codificar qualquer caractere de qualquer lugar do mundo, inclusive emojis .
- Um monte de outros detalhezinhos que você pode imaginar.

## A convenção que você deve adotar

Por fim, a escolha das convenções a seguir fica a seu critério no fim das contas. No caso da nomenclatura de identificadores, vejo pouco motivo para fugir da convenção vez que, embora ela de fato poderia ter sido melhor, você já vai estar utilizando um monte de classes e métodos de bibliotecas que seguem a convenção padrão (até mesmo os do pacote `java.lang`), o que significa que ao tentar ir contra isso, você acabaria criando um código com um estilo heterogêneo e despadronizado.

Por outro lado, quanto a escolha de tabs vs espaços, tamanho da identação, `{` no final da linha do bloco que inicia ou em sua própria linha, tamanho máximo da linha, onde colocar ou não espaços, etc, isso daí é algo que fica mais a seu critério e onde você tem mais liberdade de escolhas. Apenas pense nos prós e contras de cada abordagem antes de tomar uma decisão e seja lá qual for a decisão tomada, seja consistente e coerente nela.

## Checkstyle

Há também uma ferramenta amplamente utilizada em diversos projetos Java de nível profissional chamada [***checkstyle***](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). Essa ferramenta verifica se os códigos em linguagem Java se adequam às regras de estilos que você define no projeto, relatando qualquer violação por menor que seja.

A ferramenta é bastante flexível e configurável, tendo integração com todas as IDEs amplamente utilizadas hoje em dia e permitindo que você especifique em um arquivo XML quais são as regras de estilo a serem adotadas. A ferramenta é gratuita, de código aberto e o seu desenvolvimento é bastante ativo, tendo atualizações frequentes e já está pronto para o Java 11.

Comment: E eu achando que minhas respostas eram longas:P

Comment: Perfeito, demais até da conta, ótimas informações obtidas e fico mais seguro sabendo que varias manias são apenas manias e nada mais, ou seja, não possuem embasamento teórico e prático, acho que no fim o que deve valer é o padrão adotado pela equipe/software/empresa, o problema é que nem sempre este padrão é definido previamente, ai fica uma salada.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é usar o que seu IDE (e.g. Eclipse, Android Studio) usa, porque aí a autoformatação faz o trabalho por você.

Até onde sei o Java não tem um coding style oficial com ubiquidade comparável ao Go (que vem com gofmt) ou mesmo Python cujo coding style é determinado pelo documento PEP8 (e eu não sigo, prefiro tabs com tamanho 8).