# Qual a convenção de uso de maiúsculas e minúsculas para nomes no Java?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação

Uma vez li em algum lugar sobre as boas práticas de uso de maiúsculas e minúsculas quando se dá nome aos métodos, atributos, variaveis... no Java,
alguém me poderia me refrescar a memória?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @Articuno Esta pergunta é antiga, e semelhante a [esta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/132). Sou inclinado a fechar como duplicata, mas como o meu voto (assim como o seu) fecharia a questão imediatamente, achei melhor pedir a sua opinião. Você acha que é duplicata?

Comment: @VictorStafusa a explicação da outra está bem mais detalhada e completa, não havia reparado que poderiam ser duplicatas. Por mim, faz todo sentido o fechamento mesmo, até para facilitar localizar depois.

Comment: @Articuno Fechei como duplicata.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Pacotes (Packages)**

O prefixo do nome do pacote deve ser único, deve sempre ser escrito em letras minúsculas todo-ASCII e deve ser um dos nomes de domínio de nível superior, 
atualmente com, edu, gov, mil, net, org, códigos de duas letras identificando os países, tal como especificado na norma ISO 3166, 1981. 
Componentes subseqüentes do nome do pacote varia de acordo com uma organização próprias convenções de nomenclatura internos. 
Tais convenções podem especificar que certos componentes do nome do diretório haver divisão, departamento, projeto, máquina, ou nomes de login.

Exemplo:

```
com.sun.eng 
com.apple.quicktime.v2 
edu.cmu.cs.bovik.cheese
```

**Classes**

Os nomes de classe devem ser substantivos, em maiúsculas e minúsculas com a primeira letra de cada palavra interna em maiúscula. 
Tente manter seus nomes de classe simples e descritivo. Sempre evite palavras-ligadas , evite todas siglas e abreviaturas, seja semântico.

Exemplo:

```
class Raster; 
class ImageSprite;
```

**Interfaces**

Nomes de interfaces devem ser usadas com as primeiras letras em maiúsculas como nome de classes.

Exemplo:

```
interface RasterDelegate;
interface Storing;
```

** Métodos (Methods)**

Métodos devem ser verbos, com a letra minúscula em primeiro lugar, com a primeira letra de cada palavra interna em maiúscula.

Exemplo:

```
run(); 
runFast(); 
getBackground();
```

**Variáveis**

Os nomes de variáveis não deve começar com underscore _ ou sinal de dólar $ personagens, mesmo que ambos não são permitidos. 
Os nomes de variáveis devem ser curtos, mas significativo. A escolha de um nome variável deve ser mnemônico, isto é, concebidos para 
indicar ao observador casual a intenção da sua utilização. Um personagem nomes de variáveis devem ser evitadas, exceto para temporários 
"descartáveis" variáveis. Os nomes comuns para variáveis temporárias são i, j, k, m, n e para inteiros, c, d, e e para caracteres

Exemplo:

```
int i; 
char c; 
float myWidth;
```

**Constantes**

Os nomes de variáveis declaradas constantes de classes e de constantes ANSI deve ser todo em letras maiúsculas com palavras separadas por sublinhados ("_").

```
static final int MIN_WIDTH = 4; 
static final int MAX_WIDTH = 999;
static final int GET_THE_CPU = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Java tem uma convenção muito simples, essencialmente tudo deve ser **camelCase** (variáveis em qualquer local, incluindo atributos, métodos, pacotes).

Exceto nome de tipos (classe, interface, enumeração) que devem ser **PascalCase**.

E constantes, incluindo as dentro do `Enum`, deve ser tudo maiúsculo (**ALL_CAPS**), onde é o único local onde se admite o uso de *underline* para separar nomes.

Lembrando de [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) tradicional começa com minúscula e as demais palavras do nome seguem começando com maiúscula. Essa diferença já dá a noção de ser uma palavra diferente. Pode ter qualquer número de palavras. Algumas pessoas conhecem essa convenção por outros nomes.

PascalCase só difere pelo fato que a primeira palavra do nome já é maiúscula também. Há outros nomes para essa convenção.

Note que acrônimos devem usar camelCase também. Então use `valorIcms` e não `valorICMS`.

[Artigo da Wikipedia com exemplos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).