# Como funciona o CamelCase? Onde uso maiúsculas e minúsculas em nomes?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação

Não entendi muito bem o conceito de nomeação com maiúsculas e minusculas.

Sei que classes devem ser nomeadas com as primeiras letras maiúsculas (CamelCase), mas e objetos, variáveis, e outros identificadores?

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais as melhores práticas para dar nome as funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106061/28595)

Comment: Relacionada(talvez duplicata): [Qual a convenção de uso de maiúsculas e minúsculas para nomes no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160947/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Até que ponto devo seguir as convenções, onde posso aplicar específicos padrões de estilo próprio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/28595)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Isso é só uma convenção de nomenclatura, não há obrigatoriamente de seguir, ao menos em Java e na maioria das linguagens. Algumas levam tão a sério que não seja obrigado que elas mesmas não mantêm um padrão. O Java mesmo erra em algumas coisas, ainda que mais raras.

Isso é importante para a pessoa não ter que ficar pensando muito quando está escrevendo código e manter sempre daquele jeito, ao mesmo tempo que ajuda a leitura já que a forma escrita já dá uma indicação visual melhor do que é aquilo.

Métodos e variáveis de classe, instância ou locais devem ser `pascalCase`. Recomenda-se não usar `_` mesmo que possa.

Tem uma [guia que eu respondi bem completo para C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101), o que ajuda pensar em muita coisa. Claro que o Java segue padrões um pouco diferentes. Tem quem goste mais de um ou de outro. Há quem xingue o fato de constantes e enumerações em Java serem `ALL_CAPS` ou métodos serem `pascalCase`, tem quem acha que só assim é bom.

O importante é adotar e um padrão e seguir. Código feio, inconsistente é duro ler. Se adotar o padrão da linguagem ajuda também quem não está acostumado com seu código ler.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).