# Tempo de execução do problema das setas

Tags: c, matriz

Estou querendo resolver um problema de programação. O enunciado está aqui:

http://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/programacao/nivel1/2014f1p1_setas

Fiz um código, mas na hora de enviar dá problema em algumas entradas. Fala que deu `T: tempo limite excedido.`

Gostaria de melhorar ele, porém sem mudar a lógica. Será que teria como?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char matriz[502][502];
int n, contador, contadorx, contadory, resultado;

int AnalisaBordas(){
    //Essa funcao analisa as bordas e atribui X na matriz se elas indicarem que sai do tabuleiro
    for (contador=1;contador<n+1;contador++){
        //Analisa a primeira linha
        if(matriz[1][contador] == 'A')
            matriz[1][contador] = 'X';

        //Analisa a ultima linha
        if(matriz[n][contador] == 'V')
            matriz[n][contador] = 'X';

        //Analisa a primeira coluna
        if(matriz[contador][1] == '<')
            matriz[contador][1] = 'X';

        //Analisa a ultima coluno
        if(matriz[contador][n] == '>')
            matriz[contador][n] = 'X';
    }
    return 0;
}

int AnalisaVizinhos(int i, int j){
    //Essa funcao analisa os vizinhos da matriz [i][j]

    //Analisa a matriz a direita
    if(matriz[i][j+1] == '<')
        matriz[i][j+1] = 'X';

    //Analisa a matriz a matriz a esquerda
    if(matriz[i][j-1] == '>' )
        matriz[i][j-1] = 'X';

    //Analisa a matriz abaixo
    if(matriz[i+1][j] == 'A')
        matriz[i+1][j] = 'X';

    //Analisa a matriz acima
    if(matriz[i-1][j] == 'V')
        matriz[i-1][j] = 'X';
    return 0;
}

int main(){ 
    resultado = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);


    //loop para adicionar os caracteres
    for (contador=1;contador<=n;contador=contador+1){
        for (contadorx=0;contadorx<=n;contadorx=contadorx+1)
            matriz[contador][contadorx] = getchar();    

    }

    AnalisaBordas(); 

    //loop para executar a funcao que analisa vizinhos 
    //executada n*n vezes para trata todos os casos possiveis
    for (contadory=1;contadory<=(n*n);contadory++)
        for (contador=1;contador<=n;contador=contador+1)
            for (contadorx=1;contadorx<=n;contadorx=contadorx+1)
                if(matriz[contador][contadorx] == 'X')
                    AnalisaVizinhos(contador,contadorx);


    //loop para contar quantas posicoes sao inseguras
    for (contador=1;contador<=n;contador=contador+1)
        for (contadorx=1;contadorx<=n;contadorx=contadorx+1)
            if(matriz[contador][contadorx] == 'X')
                resultado += 1;

    printf("%d\n",(n*n - resultado));//exibe quantas posicoes sao seguras
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que suas funções retornam int se o valor não é usado pra nada?

Comment: Mas será q é isso q tá influenciando ?

Comment: Provavelmente não, foi só uma observação. Tá mais com cara de que o problema é esse seu loop triplo.

Comment: Pois é no pior dos casos o primeiro o for fica com 500*500 aí é muito para percorrer, pois ele analisa e se achar um X ele chama a função para analisar os vizinhos o que tá demorando...por isso eu gostaria de saber se dá para melhorar para fazer isso em menos tempo ou alguma coisa parecida

Comment: Isso tá com cara de que fica melhor com programação dinâmica, já que sempre que um quadrado for considerado não-seguro, todos os que apontam para ele também são não-seguros, então o resultado dele pode ser reaproveitado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para fazer várias melhorias. Vamos começar pelas mais simples:

1. Evite usar `variavel = variavel + 1`. É mais simples e menos propenso a erros usar `variavel++`.
2. Evite usar variáveis globais, pois são consideradas uma má prática de programação por vários motivos. Utilize parâmetros de funções. No exemplo abaixo eu só deixei a matriz como global, porque colocar ela como parâmetro deixaria as coisas bem mais complicadas, embora seja perfeitamente possível mesmo assim.
3. Não declare o retorno como `int` se o valor retornado não for utilizado para nada. Utilize `void` nesse caso.
4. Lembre-se que em C, a primeira posição é a posição 0, e não a posição 1. No seu algoritmo você está alocando, porém não está utilizando a posição 0.
5. Utilize as chaves nos laços `for` e nos `if`s. Para entender o porquê, veja o trecho [dessa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132) que tem o título "***Chaves após `if`, `else`, `while` e `for`***".
6. É possível colocar algumas das tarefas que estão dentro do seu `main` em funções especializadas, a fim de melhor organizar o código.

O seu algoritmo tem 3 `for`s aninhados um dentro do outro. O externo percorre [image: n^2] células (onde [image: n] é o tamanho do quadrado), enquanto que cada um dos laços internos também percorre [image: n] vezes (um para a altura e outro para a largura). Assim sendo, as células são percorridas um total de [image: n^4] vezes. Se tivermos uma matriz de 100x100, por exemplo, isso dá 100.000.000 de vezes. Se for 500x500, vai dar 62.500.000.000 vezes. O ideal seria não extrapolar muito do [image: n^2].

Isso ocorre porque o seu algoritmo faz o seguinte:

1. Marca todas as bordas que jogam para fora da matriz com `X`.
2. Procura por células vizinhas que levem para células com `X` e as marca com `X` também. Cada etapa de procura demanda olhar para todas as [image: n^2] células. Para garantir que isso acabe por marcar todas as células inseguras, propagando todos os `X`s necessários, execute isso [image: n^2] vezes.

Ocorre que esse algoritmo não é eficiente porque essa é uma forma bem lenta de propagar os `X`. No caso de após algumas iterações, o `X` parar de ser propagado, isso significa que qualquer iteração posterior não propagará mais nada. Ainda assim você insiste até que se esgote o número de iterações, ao invés de abortar o processo. Entretanto, o principal problema é que cada posição vai ser analisada um número [image: n^2] de vezes, e a grande maioria dessas análises será repetitiva e vã.

Como resolver isso?

- Podemos colocar as posições em que marcamos `X` em uma lista/fila, para analisar depois com o `AnalisaVizinhos`.
- Ao analisar uma posição da lista, a retiramos da lista/fila.
- Isso garante que uma mesma posição só entra na lista uma única vez e só é analisada uma única vez.
- Quando a lista/fila ficar vazia, não precisaremos mais chamar o `AnalisaVizinhos`. Isso garante que rodadas extras e vãs após o resultado já estar definido não serão executadas.
- Vez que uma posição é analisada uma única vez, essa variação do algoritmo vai executar [image: n^2] vezes *no pior caso*, e não mais [image: n^4] vezes *em todos os casos*.
- Com tudo isso, na matriz 100x100 ao invés de fazer 100.000.000 iterações **sempre**, serão feitas apenas 10.000 **no pior caso**. Na matriz 500x500 ao invés de fazer um total de 62.500.000.000 iterações **sempre**, vamos fazer 250.000 **no pior caso**. Lembrando que o caso médio tende a ser bem menor que o pior caso.

Enfim, a ideia aqui é apenas rastrear quais são as posições que valem a pena ser analisadas e em qual ordem ao invés de simplesmente analisar todas cegamente um número bem grande de vezes.

É verdade que esse algoritmo é significativamente diferente do seu algoritmo original. Entretanto, não vejo forma de salvar o seu algoritmo original sem introduzir algumas mudanças significativas.

Aqui vai a implementação resultante:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char matriz[500][500];

// Esta função analisa as bordas e atribui X na matriz se elas indicarem que sai do tabuleiro
int AnalisaBordas(int linhas, int colunas, int *fila_linhas, int *fila_colunas) {
    int contador;
    int posicao_fila = 0;

    for (contador = 0; contador < colunas; contador++) {
        // Analisa a primeira linha.
        if (matriz[0][contador] == 'A') {
            matriz[0][contador] = 'X';
            fila_linhas[posicao_fila] = 0;
            fila_colunas[posicao_fila] = contador;
            posicao_fila++;
        }

        // Analisa a última linha.
        if (matriz[linhas - 1][contador] == 'V') {
            matriz[linhas - 1][contador] = 'X';
            fila_linhas[posicao_fila] = linhas - 1;
            fila_colunas[posicao_fila] = contador;
            posicao_fila++;
        }
    }

    for (contador = 0; contador < linhas; contador++) {
        // Analisa a primeira coluna.
        if (matriz[contador][0] == '<') {
            matriz[contador][0] = 'X';
            fila_linhas[posicao_fila] = contador;
            fila_colunas[posicao_fila] = 0;
            posicao_fila++;
        }

        // Analisa a última coluna.
        if (matriz[contador][colunas - 1] == '>') {
            matriz[contador][colunas - 1] = 'X';
            fila_linhas[posicao_fila] = contador;
            fila_colunas[posicao_fila] = colunas - 1;
            posicao_fila++;
        }
    }

    return posicao_fila;
}

// Esta função analisa os vizinhos da célula [i][j].
void AnalisaVizinhos(int i, int j, int *fila_linhas, int *fila_colunas, int *posicao_fila) {

    // Analisa a célula a direita.
    if (matriz[i][j + 1] == '<') {
        matriz[i][j + 1] = 'X';
        fila_linhas[*posicao_fila] = i;
        fila_colunas[*posicao_fila] = j + 1;
        (*posicao_fila)++;
    }

    // Analisa a célula a esquerda.
    if (matriz[i][j - 1] == '>') {
        matriz[i][j - 1] = 'X';
        fila_linhas[*posicao_fila] = i;
        fila_colunas[*posicao_fila] = j - 1;
        (*posicao_fila)++;
    }

    // Analisa a célula abaixo.
    if (matriz[i + 1][j] == 'A') {
        matriz[i + 1][j] = 'X';
        fila_linhas[*posicao_fila] = i + 1;
        fila_colunas[*posicao_fila] = j;
        (*posicao_fila)++;
    }

    // Analisa a célula acima.
    if (matriz[i - 1][j] == 'V') {
        matriz[i-  1][j] = 'X';
        fila_linhas[*posicao_fila] = i - 1;
        fila_colunas[*posicao_fila] = j;
        (*posicao_fila)++;
    }
}

void PropagaFila(int *fila_linhas, int *fila_colunas, int tamanho_inicial_fila) {
    int inicio_fila = 0;
    int fim_fila = tamanho_inicial_fila;
    while (inicio_fila < fim_fila) {
        AnalisaVizinhos(fila_linhas[inicio_fila], fila_colunas[inicio_fila], fila_linhas, fila_colunas, &fim_fila);
        inicio_fila++;
    }
}

// Loop para adicionar os caracteres.
void PreencherMatriz(int linhas, int colunas) {
    int linha, coluna;
    for (linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        for (coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {
            char c;
            do {
                c = getchar();
            } while (c != '<' && c != '>' && c != 'V' && c != 'A');
            matriz[linha][coluna] = c;
        }
    }
}

// Loop para adicionar os caracteres.
int ContarMatriz(int linhas, int colunas) {
    int seguras = 0;
    int linha, coluna;
    for (linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        for (coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {
            if (matriz[linha][coluna] != 'X') seguras++;
        }
    }
    return seguras;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 0 || n > 500) {
        printf("Tamanho invalido para a matriz");
        return 1;
    }

    PreencherMatriz(n, n);

    // Cria a fila.
    int fila_linhas[500];
    int fila_colunas[500];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        fila_linhas[i] = fila_colunas[i] = -1;
    }

    int tamanho_inicial_fila = AnalisaBordas(n, n, fila_linhas, fila_colunas);
    PropagaFila(fila_linhas, fila_colunas, tamanho_inicial_fila);

    int seguras = ContarMatriz(n, n);

    printf("%d\n", seguras); // Exibe quantas posições são seguras.
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/jg5uk1)

Note que eu separei o conceito de linhas e colunas na maioria das funções para que o algoritmo funcione com quaisquer matrizes retangulares, mesmo as não-quadradas.

Há algumas melhorias possíveis, para evitar ter que ter a matriz como uma variável global, simplificar a repetição de códigos e melhor encapsular e modularizar tanto a fila quanto a matriz dentro de estruturas de dados especializadas. Entretanto, o algoritmo básico continuaria o mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara...melhorou muito essas dicas!!! E esse código aí me ajudou bastante!!!