# Erro DataBase Locked Sqlite/Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, sql-insert

Tenho o seguinte problema: em um insert que estou tentando realizar, não não sei definir se é erro no banco ou algo na programação em java, porém toda vez que tento realizar um insert da tabela cliente me retorna o erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: database locked

Até então estava tudo ok no insert porém tive que refazer o banco a partir dai começou o problema revisei o código porem parece estar tudo correto, segue abaixo código do insert:

```
public class clienteDAO {   
    public void Create(cliente c){    
       Connection conn = javaConnect.ConnectDb();

       PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cliente (cliente_nome,cliente_rg,cliente_cpf,end_rua,end_numero,end_bairro,end_cidade,end_estado,end_cep,telefone_celular, telefone_residencial, telefone_extra, cliente_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, c.getNome());
            pstmt.setString(2, c.getRg());
            pstmt.setString(3, c.getCpf());
            pstmt.setString(4, c.getRua());
            pstmt.setString(5, c.getNumero());
            pstmt.setString(6, c.getBairro());
            pstmt.setString(7, c.getCidade());
            pstmt.setString(8, c.getEstado());
            pstmt.setString(9, c.getCep());
            pstmt.setString(10, c.getTelefone1());
            pstmt.setString(11, c.getTelefone2());
            pstmt.setString(12, c.getTelefone3());
            pstmt.setString(13, c.getEmail());


            pstmt.executeUpdate();


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro Realizado!");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao salvar: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Tentei encontrar o erro tbm na criação da tabela mas também não consegui identificar qualquer erro, segue código que utilizei para criar a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
id_cliente integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
cliente_cpf varchar(20),
cliente_nome varchar(60),
end_rua varchar(40),
cliente_rg varchar(20),
end_bairro varchar(50),
end_estado varchar(40),
end_cidade varchar(40),
end_cep varchar(20),
end_numero varchar(10),
telefone_contato1 varchar(12),
telefone_contato2 varchar(12),
telefone_contato3 varchar(12),
cliente_email varchar(30)
)
```

Bom, agora eu não tenho ideia se o erro esta no banco ou na programação em Java.

Revisei tbm os códigos do get/Set mas aparentam estar corretos também.

Comment: Muito provavelmente está largando ele aberto em algum outro lugar que tem exclusividade.

Comment: Você se refere a conexão com o banco ?

Comment: Isso mesmo.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está abrindo o `Connection` e o `PreparedStatement` mas não os está fechando adequadamente. Se eles forem largados e esquecidos abertos, é bem provável que acabem causando erros como esse que você está tendo.

A solução é [usar o *try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).

Eis o seu código revisado:

```
public class ClienteDAO {
    private static final String SQL_INSERT =
            "INSERT INTO cliente (cliente_nome,cliente_rg,cliente_cpf,end_rua,end_numero,end_bairro,end_cidade,end_estado,end_cep,telefone_celular, telefone_residencial, telefone_extra, cliente_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    public void create(Cliente c) {
       try (
           Connection conn = JavaConnect.connectDb();
           PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
       ) {
            pstmt.setString(1, c.getNome());
            pstmt.setString(2, c.getRg());
            pstmt.setString(3, c.getCpf());
            pstmt.setString(4, c.getRua());
            pstmt.setString(5, c.getNumero());
            pstmt.setString(6, c.getBairro());
            pstmt.setString(7, c.getCidade());
            pstmt.setString(8, c.getEstado());
            pstmt.setString(9, c.getCep());
            pstmt.setString(10, c.getTelefone1());
            pstmt.setString(11, c.getTelefone2());
            pstmt.setString(12, c.getTelefone3());
            pstmt.setString(13, c.getEmail());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro Realizado!");    
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao salvar: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Ah, e note que mudei o nome do método para `create` e o nome das classes para `Cliente` e `ClienteDAO` para deixá-lo [de acordo com as convenções da linguagem Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132). Também note que por esse motivo, usei `JavaConnect.connectDb();` ao invés de `javaConnect.ConnectDb();`.

Comment: Realmente entendi a situação e percebi que o erro está em meu login onde não utilizo deste Recurso, obrigado, serviu de grande ajuda, vou tentar aprender a utilizar o try-with-resources.