# Utilizando try-with-resources em código Java

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

Tenho um seguinte problema, não estou conseguindo passar um código que tenho atualmente e que está errado, ele funciona mas não fecha a conexão com banco e dá muito erro, e queria usar ele com o recurso do try-with-resources.

Segue código original sem utilização do try-with-resources:

```
private void entrar() {

       conn = JavaConnect.connectDb();
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where nome_usuario= ? and senha_usuario= ?";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,jtxtUsuario.getText());
            pst.setString(2,jtxtSenha.getText());

            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                jfrmPrincipal principal = new jfrmPrincipal();
                principal.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Senha ou Usuário Incorreto");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }          
    }
```

Tentei realizar a mesma funcionalidade de cima mas não consegui, e atualmente este código fica no próprio JFRAME pois não consegui colocar ele em uma classe e depois chamar a classe para a consulta no botão do frame, pois não consigo chamar o "jtxtUsuario" na classe por exemplo, isso é possível certo ? alguém pode me mostrar como seria a maneira correta ?

Estou tentando aprender mas parece que isso realmente não estou conseguindo, rs.

Para ser bem franco com todos, fiquei sabendo do try-with-resources hoje graças ao apoio de um outro usuário da comunidade, isso está me deixando com dificuldade de refazer este código.

Comment: Relacionada: [Dúvidas sobre a integração do MySQL com Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172816/28595)

Comment: Você teve alguma dificuldade com [a minha outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173380/132)? Por sinal, neste seu código, onde é que você está declarando `conn` e `pst`?

Comment: sim @VictorStafusa, quando postei meu outro código do insert você passou ele todo pronto, e fiquei muito agradecido, neste caso agora que é uma validação estou tentando reescrever ele com o apoio do link que você me passou da solução try-with-resources, porem no login é uma validação e não estou conseguindo fazer ele da maneira correta, o conn e pst estão declarados um pouco mais acima, acabou ficando fora da postagem, estão declarados como null

Comment: @VictorStafusa vou tentar até mais tarde, se eu não conseguir vou fazer outra pergunta na comunidade do meu código errado para ver se consigo ajuda para me apontarem os meus erros.

Comment: Leo, acabei de atualizar [essa outra resposta minha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172910/132), que eu acredito que você já tenha lido, para elucidar esse problema. Eu pensava que tinha abordado tudo que precisava lá, mas você achou um ponto que havia esquecido de mencionar. Muito obrigado.