# Quando crio duas tabelas no SQLite Android, somente uma funciona

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo de teste que requer duas tabelas (`aluno` e `disciplina`) na classe `DataHelper`. Crio duas tabelas, porém na hora de fazer testes, somente a tabela `Aluno` funciona. Em resumo: a aplicação tem algumas funcionalidades (inserir aluno, inserir disciplina, apagar aluno, apagar disciplina, entre outras) e todos os métodos funcionam para a tabela do aluno, porém nenhum método funciona pra tabela da disciplina. O que isso pode ser?

Abaixo, a classe em que as tabelas são criadas (`DataHelper`) seguidas das classes que manipulam cada tabela, são essas tabelas `aluno` (`AlunoDao`) e disciplina (`DisciplinaDao`) respectivamente e uma classe que abre e fecha o banco de dados (`Dao`):

```java
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DataHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      try{
            StringBuilder sbAluno = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbDisciplina = new StringBuilder();
            sbAluno.append( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [disciplina](\n" +
                    "    [iddisciplina] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \n" +
                    "    [nomedisc] TEXT NOT NULL, \n" +
                    "    [tutor] TEXT NOT NULL);");
            db.execSQL(String.valueOf(sbAluno));

            sbDisciplina.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [aluno](\n" +
                    "    [idaluno] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \n" +
                    "    [nome] TEXT NOT NULL, \n" +
                    "    [curso] TEXT NOT NULL);" );
            db.execSQL(String.valueOf(sbDisciplina));

        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try{

            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

            sb.append("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [aluno];" + "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [disciplina];" );

            String [] comando = sb.toString().split(";");

            for (int i = 0; i < comando.length ; i++) {
                db.execSQL(comando[i].toLowerCase()); //toLowerCase torna todas as letras minusculas
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }

        onCreate(db);

    }
```

```java
public class DisciplinaDao extends Dao {

    private static final String TABELA = "disciplina";
    private static final String IDDISCIPLINA = "iddisciplina";
    private static final String NOMEDISC = "nomedisc";
    private static final String TUTOR = "tutor";


    public DisciplinaDao(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void inserirDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina){
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(IDDISCIPLINA, disciplina.getIddisciplina());
        cv.put(NOMEDISC, disciplina.getNomedisc());
        cv.put(TUTOR, disciplina.getTutor());
        //
        db.insert(TABELA, null, cv);
        //
        FecharBanco();

    }

    public void atualizarDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina){
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        //
        String Filtro = "iddisciplina = ?";
        String [] argumentos = { String.valueOf(disciplina.getIddisciplina()) };
        //
        cv.put(NOMEDISC, disciplina.getNomedisc());
        cv.put(TUTOR, disciplina.getTutor());
        //
        db.update(TABELA, cv, Filtro, argumentos);
        //
        FecharBanco();
    }

    public void apagarDisciplina(int iddisciplina){
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        String Filtro = "iddisciplina = ?";
        String [] argumentos = { String.valueOf(iddisciplina) };
        //
        db.delete(TABELA, Filtro, argumentos);
        //
        FecharBanco();
    }

    public Disciplina obterContatoByID(int iddisciplina){
        Disciplina cAux = null;
        //
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        Cursor cursor = null;
        //
        try{
            String [] argumentos = { String.valueOf(iddisciplina) };

            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append(" select * from disciplina where iddisciplina = ? ");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), argumentos);

            //avançar os dados se nao conseguir passar pro proximo ele sai do while
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                cAux = new Disciplina();

                cAux.setIddisciplina(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IDDISCIPLINA)));
                cAux.setNomedisc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOMEDISC)));
                cAux.setTutor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TUTOR)));
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
        }
        //
        FecharBanco();
        //
        return cAux;
    }

    public ArrayList<HMAux> obterListaDisciplina(){
        ArrayList<HMAux> dados = new ArrayList<>();
        //
        AbrirBanco();
        //

        Cursor cursor = null;
        //
        try{

            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append(" select iddisciplina, nomedisc from disciplina order by nomedisc ");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), null);

            //avançar os dados se nao conseguir passar pro proximo ele sai do while
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                HMAux hmAux = new HMAux();

                hmAux.put(HMAux.id_disciplina, String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(IDDISCIPLINA))));
                hmAux.put(HMAux.TEXTO_02, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOMEDISC)));

                dados.add(hmAux);

                }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
        }
        //
        FecharBanco();
        //
        return dados;
    }

    public int proximoID(){
        int proId = 0;
        //
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        Cursor cursor = null;
        //
        try{

            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append("select max(iddisciplina)+1 as id from disciplina");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), null);
            int x = 10;
            //avançar os dados se nao conseguir passar pro proximo ele sai do while
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                proId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            }
            if(proId == 0){
                proId = 1 ;
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
        }

        //
        FecharBanco();
        //
        return proId;
    }

}
```

```java
public class AlunoDao extends Dao {

    private static final String TABELA = "aluno";
    private static final String IDALUNO = "idaluno";
    private static final String NOME = "nome";
    private static final String CURSO = "curso";


    public AlunoDao(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void inserirAluno(Aluno aluno){
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(IDALUNO, aluno.getIdaluno());
        cv.put(NOME, aluno.getNome());
        cv.put(CURSO, aluno.getCurso());
        //
        db.insert(TABELA, null, cv);
        //
        FecharBanco();
    }

    public void atualizarAluno(Aluno aluno){
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        //
        String Filtro = "idaluno = ?";
        String [] argumentos = { String.valueOf(aluno.getIdaluno()) };
        //
        //cv.put(IDCONTATO, contato.getIdcontato());
        cv.put(NOME, aluno.getNome());
        cv.put(CURSO, aluno.getCurso());
        //
        db.update(TABELA, cv, Filtro, argumentos);
        //
        FecharBanco();
    }

    public void apagarAluno(int idaluno){
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        String Filtro = "idaluno = ?";
        String [] argumentos = { String.valueOf(idaluno) };
        //
        db.delete(TABELA, Filtro, argumentos);
        //
        FecharBanco();
    }

    public Aluno obterAlunoByID(long idaluno){
        Aluno cAux = null;
        //
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        Cursor cursor = null;
        //
        try{
            String [] argumentos = { String.valueOf(idaluno) };

            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append(" select * from aluno where idaluno = ? ");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), argumentos);

            //avançar os dados se nao conseguir passar pro proximo ele sai do while
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                cAux = new Aluno();

                cAux.setIdaluno(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IDALUNO)));
                cAux.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));
                cAux.setCurso(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CURSO)));

            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
        }
        //
        FecharBanco();
        //
        return cAux;
    }

    public ArrayList<HMAux> obterListaAluno(){
        ArrayList<HMAux> dados = new ArrayList<>();
        //
        AbrirBanco();
        //

        Cursor cursor = null;
        //
        try{

            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append(" select idaluno, nome from aluno order by nome ");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), null);

            //avançar os dados se nao conseguir passar pro proximo ele sai do while
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                HMAux hmAux = new HMAux();

                hmAux.put(HMAux.id, String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(IDALUNO))));
                hmAux.put(HMAux.TEXTO_01, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));

                dados.add(hmAux);

                }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
        }
        //
        FecharBanco();
        //
        return dados;
    }

    public int proximoID(){
        int proId = 0;
        //
        AbrirBanco();
        //
        Cursor cursor = null;
        //
        try{

            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append(" select max(idaluno)+1 as id from aluno ");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), null);

            //avançar os dados se nao conseguir passar pro proximo ele sai do while
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                proId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            }
            if(proId == 0){
                proId = 1 ;
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (cursor != null){
                cursor.close();
                cursor = null;
            }
        }

        //
        FecharBanco();
        //
        return proId;
    }

}
```

```java
public class Dao {

    private Context context;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Dao(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void AbrirBanco(){
        DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper(
            context,
            Constantes.BANCO,
            null,
            Constantes.VERSAO
        );

        this.db = dataHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public void FecharBanco(){
        if (db != null){
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ao utilizar os métodos da classe `AlunoDao` ocorre tudo normal. Porém, ao utilizar os métodos da classe `DisciplinaDao`, não funcionam, mas também não dá erro. Criei os dois da mesma forma e com os mesmos métodos. Não sei o que pode ser feito. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Dá algum erro? Ponha o código de um dos métodos que não funcionam.

Comment: tenta fazer assim ó, adicone essa linha em ambas as tabelas: `db.execSQL("commit");` que pode ser isso

Comment: Você criou as duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo ou adicionou a tabela "disciplina" depois?

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. As duas  estão sendo criadas ou apenas a de Alunos? Se as duas tabelas estão sendo criadas o problema não está com a sua classe DataHelper, mas sim com as classes que manipulam os dados delas.

Comment: As duas são criadas porém só uma funciona. Editei a pergunta e coloquei todos os detalhes do meu projeto, obrigado

Comment: Não coloque [resolvido] no título. Ao invés disso, marque como aceita a resposta que resolveu o seu problema. Se nenhuma das respostas tiver resolvido o seu problema e você mesmo tiver encontrado a solução sozinho, poste você mesmo a resposta.

Comment: Aqui vai o seu comentário que você postou na pergunta: "**Pelo que pesquisei o problema está na versão do banco de dados, a solução que encontrei foi desinstalar e instalar o apk, isso resolveu meu problema. Link de onde a solução foi encontrada:_ < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069532/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-table-admin-while-compiling-i >**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na versão do banco de dados, a solução foi desinstalar e instalar o apk, isso resolveu meu problema. Link de onde a solução foi encontrada: stackoverflow.com/questions/21069532/…

Answer (score 0):

Olhando as suas classes `AlunoDao` e `DisciplinaDao`, as mesmas são bem equivalentes. As pouquíssimas diferenças de algo que há em uma e não na outra não devem fazer efeito (linhas comentadas, linhas em branco, um `int x = 10;` que nunca é usado e o nome do método `obterContatoByID` ao invés de `obterDisciplinaByID`).

Entretanto, há um ponto diferente que vale uma investigação mais a fundo:

```
                hmAux.put(HMAux.id, String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(IDALUNO))));
                hmAux.put(HMAux.TEXTO_01, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));

                hmAux.put(HMAux.id_disciplina, String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(IDDISCIPLINA))));
                hmAux.put(HMAux.TEXTO_02, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOMEDISC)));
```

Será que não há algo errado em relação a esse `TEXTO_01` e `TEXTO_02`? Ou talvez quanto ao fato de um usar `id` e o outro `id_disciplina`?

Aliás, por que você devolve `List<HMAux>` nos dois casos ao invés de `List<Aluno>` e `List<Disciplina>`? Vou assumir que isso é um erro e que deveria ser esses dois últimos.

Quanto mais, o seu código tem sérios problemas de qualidade. O primeiro deles é que você devia [usar o *try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) (veja nesse link como e por quê).

Se não puder usar o *try-with-resources*, ao menos certifique-se de fechar tudo em um bloco `finally`. Porém, uma vez que você já está usando a sintaxe de diamante (`<>` no construtor), então você já está usando pelo menos o Java 7, logo pode usar o *try-with-resources*.

Outro problema é que você usa `StringBuilder`s sem necessidade. Por exemplo:

```
            StringBuilder comando = new StringBuilder();
            comando.append(" select * from disciplina where iddisciplina = ? ");

            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando.toString(), argumentos);
```

Poxa, seria bem mais fácil, mais simples, mais óbvio, mais direto e mais lógico se você fizesse isso:

```
            String comando = " select * from disciplina where iddisciplina = ? ";
            cursor = db.rawQuery(comando, argumentos);
```

Isso fica ainda pior na sua classe `DataHelper`, onde você concatena as strings para então separá-las de novo e até mesmo usa um `for` sem necessidade alguma.

Uma outra coisa que noto, é que todos os seus métodos dos DAOs começam com `AbrirBanco()` e terminam com `FecharBanco()`. Isso é esperado, mas isso também significa que a referência `db` não tem serventia nenhuma fora da execução de algum desses métodos. Mais do que isso, o `db` que é usado por um dos métodos dos DAOs tem um escopo que nasce, vive e morre inteiramente dentro de um único método de cada vez. Isso é um forte indício de que o uso de variáveis locais seria mais apropriado.

E por favor, se atente às [regras de nomenclatura da linguagem Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132). Ou seja, a menos que você tenha uma razão muito forte e muito bem justificada para fazer diferente, nomes de métodos e de variáveis locais **DEVEM** começar com letras minúsculas.

Comer exceções (capturar e e não fazer nada com ela depois) é uma péssima prática de programação. **NUNCA** faça isso:

```
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
```

Uma vez que a exceção `android.database.SQLException` herda de `java.lang.RuntimeException`, você não precisa tratá-la aqui. Entretanto, o código que for fazer uso dos seus DAOs deveria ser capaz de tratar isso.

Além disso, em uma classe chamada `Aluno`, um método `getIdaluno()` tem um nome um tanto redundante. O nome ser `getId()` já é suficiente. Afinal, se estou na classe `Aluno`, um método `getId()` obviamente só vai poder se referir ao id do aluno, e portanto ele não precisa se chamar `getIdaluno()`. O mesmo pode ser dito acerca de outros métodos e também de colunas no banco de dados tais como `nomedisc` e `iddisciplina` por exemplo.

Há também um princípio de programação orientada a objetos que diz que você deve depender de abstrações, e não de implementações. Um efeito direto disso é que você deve sempre preferir, se possível, referenciar interfaces ao invés de classes que implementam essas interfaces. Assim sendo, evite definir tipos que seja `ArrayList<AlgumaCoisa>` quando `List<AlgumaCoisa>` já serve.

Um outro princípio de prgramação diz que composição é melhor que herança. Podemos eliminar a sua herança nos DAOs ao separar o conteúdo da superclasse em uma nova classse que é **usada** pelos DAOs ao invés de ser **herdada** por eles. Essa abordagem provê um acoplamento mais fraco, um melhor encapsulamento e uma melhor organização do código. Coloquei o comportaneto da sua superclasse `Dao` em uma classe `ConnectionFactory`.

Simplificando todo o seu código, fica assim:

```java
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String CREATE_ALUNO = ""
            + "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [aluno] (\n" +
            + "    [id] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \n" +
            + "    [nome] TEXT NOT NULL, \n" +
            + "    [curso] TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static final String CREATE_DISCIPLINA = ""
            + "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [disciplina] (\n" +
            + "    [id] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \n" +
            + "    [nome] TEXT NOT NULL, \n" +
            + "    [tutor] TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static final String DROP_ALUNO =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [aluno];";

    private static final String DROP_DISCIPLINA =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [disciplina];";

    public DataHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ALUNO);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DISCIPLINA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_ALUNO);
        db.execSQL(DROP_DISCIPLINA);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

```java
public final class ConnectionFactory {

    private final DataHelper dataHelper;

    public ConnectionFactory(Context context) {
        this.dataHelper = new DataHelper(context, Constantes.BANCO, null, Constantes.VERSAO);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase conectar() throws SQLiteException {
        return dataHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

```java
public class AlunoDao {

    private static final String TABELA = "aluno";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String NOME = "nome";
    private static final String CURSO = "curso";

    private static final String FILTRO_ID = "id = ?";

    private static final String SELECT_BY_ID_SQL =
            "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE id = ?";

    private static final String SELECT_LIST_SQL =
            "SELECT id, nome FROM aluno ORDER BY nome";

    private static final String SELECT_PROXIMO_ID_SQL =
            "SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS max_id FROM aluno";

    private final ConnectionFactory factory;

    public AlunoDao(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void inserirAluno(Aluno aluno) {
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar()) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(IDALUNO, aluno.getId());
            cv.put(NOME, aluno.getNome());
            cv.put(CURSO, aluno.getCurso());
            db.insert(TABELA, null, cv);
        }
    }

    public void atualizarAluno(Aluno aluno) {
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar()) {
            String[] argumentos = { String.valueOf(aluno.getId()) };
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NOME, aluno.getNome());
            cv.put(CURSO, aluno.getCurso());
            db.update(TABELA, cv, FILTRO_ID, argumentos);
        }
    }

    public void apagarAluno(int idAluno) {
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar()) {
            String[] argumentos = { String.valueOf(idAluno) };
            db.delete(TABELA, FILTRO_ID, argumentos);
        }
    }

    public Aluno obterAlunoByID(long idAluno) {
        String[] argumentos = { String.valueOf(idAluno) };

        try (
            SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_BY_ID_SQL, argumentos);
        ) {
            if (!cursor.moveToNext()) return null;
            Aluno aux = new Aluno();
            aux.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
            aux.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));
            aux.setCurso(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CURSO)));
            return aux;
        }
    }

    public List<Aluno> obterListaAluno() {
        try (
            SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_LIST_SQL, null);
        ) {
            List<Aluno> lista = new ArrayList<>();

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Aluno aux = new Aluno();
                aux.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
                aux.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));
                aux.setCurso(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CURSO)));
                lista.add(aux);
            }

            return lista;
        }
    }

    public int proximoID() {
        try (
            SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_PROXIMO_ID_SQL, null);
        ) {
            if (!cursor.moveToNext()) return 1;
            return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_max"));
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class DisciplinaDao {

    private static final String TABELA = "disciplina";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String NOME = "nome";
    private static final String TUTOR = "tutor";

    private static final String FILTRO_ID = "id = ?";

    private static final String SELECT_BY_ID_SQL =
            "SELECT * FROM disciplina WHERE id = ?";

    private static final String SELECT_LIST_HMAUX_SQL =
            "SELECT id, nome FROM disciplina ORDER BY nome";

    private static final String SELECT_PROXIMO_ID_SQL =
            "SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS max_id FROM disciplina";

    private final ConnectionFactory factory;

    public AlunoDao(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void inserirDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina) {
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar()) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(ID, disciplina.getId());
            cv.put(NOME, disciplina.getNome());
            cv.put(TUTOR, disciplina.getTutor());
            db.insert(TABELA, null, cv);
        }
    }

    public void atualizarDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina) {
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar()) {
            String[] argumentos = { String.valueOf(disciplina.getId()) };
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NOME, disciplina.getNome());
            cv.put(TUTOR, disciplina.getTutor());
            db.update(TABELA, cv, FILTRO_ID, argumentos);
        }
    }

    public void apagarDisciplina(int idDisciplina) {
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar()) {
            String[] argumentos = { String.valueOf(idDisciplina) };
            db.delete(TABELA, FILTRO_ID, argumentos);
        }
    }

    public Disciplina obterDisciplinaByID(long idDisciplina) {
        String[] argumentos = { String.valueOf(idDisciplina) };

        try (
            SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_BY_ID_SQL, argumentos);
        ) {
            if (!cursor.moveToNext()) return null;
            Disciplina aux = new Disciplina();
            aux.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
            aux.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));
            aux.setTutor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TUTOR)));
            return aux;
        }
    }

    public List<Disciplina> obterListaDisciplina() {
        try (
            SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_LIST_SQL, null);
        ) {
            List<Disciplina> lista = new ArrayList<>();

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Disciplina aux = new Disciplina();
                aux.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)));
                aux.setNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));
                aux.setTutor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TUTOR)));
                lista.add(aux);
            }

            return lista;
        }
    }

    public int proximoID() {
        try (
            SQLiteDatabase db = factory.conectar();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_PROXIMO_ID_SQL, null);
        ) {
            if (!cursor.moveToNext()) return 1;
            return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_max"));
        }
    }
}
```

Você não especificou onde você está usando os seus DAOs, mas suspeito que esse possa ser o seu grande problema. Do jeito que você usava, cada vez que você abria uma conexão, um nova instância de `DataHelper` e uma nova instância de `SQLiteDatabase` era criada. Do jeito que eu fiz, se você usar a mesma instância de `ConnectionFactory` e (re)utilizá-la para instanciar todos os DAOs, este problema será resolvido, uma vez que um único `DataHelper` será criado. Note que essa solução não seria possível sem a eliminação da herança.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimento e dicas, certamente me atentarei mais a esses "detalhes"! A solução de fato não foi oque você sugeriu, mas toda sua explicação foi de grande ajuda. :)