# Aprendendo a utilizar ENUM em Java

Tags: java, enums

Boa tarde.

Estou aprendendo a utilizar os tipos `enum` no Java e enfrentando alguns problemas.

Primeiramente, criei meu `enum` da seguinte forma:

```
public enum enumUpdateAction {
    NEW(0), CHANGE(1), DELETE(2), DELETE_THRU(3), DELETE_FROM(4);

    public int codigo;

    enumUpdateAction(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }
}
```

Agora, preciso utilizar tal enum dentro de um Switch, em outra classe:

```
public static LinkedList<LinkedList<Eventos>> Working(enum_type tipo, enum_updateAction updateAction) {

    switch (Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction()) {

        case enum_updateAction.NEW://enum_updateAction.NEW: // 0 = new
                ArrayEventos.add(InserirOrdenado(ArrayEventos, Ordem), Ordem);
                break;

    }


}
```

O `Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction()` retorna um `int`. Eu poderia utilizar nos cases números de 0 a 2, mas como sei que cada número representa `BID`, `OFFER` ou `TRADE`, estou tentando utilizar essas palavras direto no `switch`, com o auxílio do `enum`. Entretanto, recebo que "*enum_updateAction.NEW cannot be converted to int*". Alguém sabe me dizer como pego o valor número do `NEW` do `enum`, e não a palavra `NEW` em si?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo `enum` tem um método chamado `ordinal()` que dá a posição no qual ele foi declarado dentro da classe, sendo o primeiro elemento o de `ordinal() == 0`. Ora, isso é exatamente o que o seu campo `codigo` faz. Assim sendo, você não precisa usar esse campo para reinventar a roda, basta usar o `ordinal()`.

```
public enum EnumUpdateAction {
    NEW, CHANGE, DELETE, DELETE_THRU, DELETE_FROM;
}
```

Além disso, todo `enum` tem um método `values()` que retorna um array do mesmo tipo do `enum` contendo os elementos desse `enum` na ordem em que são definidos. Você pode usar isso para traduzir os valores do `ordinal()` para os elementos.

No `switch`, você pode usar os elementos do `enum`s diretamente, referenciando-os pelos respectivos nomes. Não precisa de nenhum código `int` para isso:

```
public static List<? extends List<Eventos>> working(EnumType tipo, EnumUpdateAction updateAction) {

    switch (EnumUpdateAction.values()[eventos.get(0).getUpdateAction()]) {
        case NEW:
            ArrayEventos.add(inserirOrdenado(arrayEventos, ordem), ordem);
            break;
        case CHANGE:
            // ...
            break;
        case DELETE:
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Também noto que se `eventos.get(0)` retornasse `EnumUpdateAction` ao invés de `int`, o seu `switch` ficaria mais simples:

```
switch (eventos.get(0)) {
```

Além disso, por favor, obedeça as [convenções da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132).

E noto que talvez no seu código, o que você realmente queria era um `switch (updateAction) { ... }`.

[Veja no ideone um exemplo com `enum` em `switch`](http://ideone.com/TM8jAM):

```
class EnumComSwitch {
    private static enum MeuEnum {
        NEW, CHANGE, DELETE, BLABLA;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuEnum elemento = MeuEnum.CHANGE;
        switch (elemento) {
            case NEW:
                System.out.println("Este é o NEW");
                break;
            case CHANGE:
                System.out.println("Este é o CHANGE");
                break;
            case DELETE:
                System.out.println("Este é o DELETE");
                break;
            case BLABLA:
                System.out.println("Este é o BLABLA");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O `switch(eventos.get(0))` não é uma opção. Esse `Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction` retorna um int que leio de um arquivo, sendo ele de 0 a 4. Dependendo do que ele retornar, eu tomo uma ação (daí o switch). Entretanto, quando utilizo NEW direto no case, é apresentada uma lista imensa de opções para importação. Tentei instanciar o ENUM para solucionar, entretanto o compilador mesmo informou que ele já é instanciado. Estou buscando alternativas, entretanto muito obrigado pelas informações. Sobre as convenções de linguagem, estou voltando a estudar java por agora, stou um pouco perdido ainda

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Não precisa de importação nenhuma, basta importar a classe do `enum` (que você já deve estar importando) e nada mais. **Ignore a lista de sugestões de importação.** - Quando essa lista aparecer, aperte ESC. Além disso, uma das premissas básicas do `enum` é a de serem um conjunto fixo e imutável de objetos, e portanto não deveriam ser instanciáveis, pois isso faria com que deixassem de ser um conjunto fixo e imutável.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Acrescentei um exemplo. Veja ele funcionando aqui: http://ideone.com/TM8jAM

Comment: Beleza cara. Muito obrigado pelo esforço e paciência de vocês. Agora estou entendendo como trabalhar com esse `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente vou utilizar outro nome para `enum`, considerando a conveção de código, que classes devem começar com letra maiúscula e `_` deve ser evitado.

Existem várias formas que fazer a comparação que você deseja, uma delas é transformar o `int` que representa noo `enum` (consisderando que você possa colocar qualquer código em qualquer ordem) desejado.

```
public enum Type {
  BID(0), OFFER(1), TRADE(2);

  public final int codigo;

  private Type(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
  }

  public int getCodigo() {
    return this.codigo;
  }

  public static Type getType(int codigo) {
    for(Type type : Type.values()) {
      if (type.getCodigo() == codigo) {
        return type;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Assim sua comparação ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public static LinkedList<LinkedList<Eventos>> working() {
  Type type = Type.getType(Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction());

  switch(type) {
      case Type.NEW:
        arrayEventos.add(InserirOrdenado(arrayEventos, ordem), ordem);
        break;
  }
}
```

Note que utilizei o método `Type#get` para transformar o `int` do `Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction()` para obter o `enum` referente a ele.

---

A segunda forma seria, utilizando a implementação do `enum` anterior, fazer a verificação da seguinte forma:

```
public static LinkedList<LinkedList<Eventos>> working() {
  switch(Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction()) {
      case Type.NEW.getCodigo():
        ArrayEventos.add(InserirOrdenado(arrayEventos, ordem), ordem);
        break;
  }
}
```

Caso você garanta que a ordem será realmente referente ao `int` que utilizará existe uma solução [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186559/59479).

---

**Referência:**

Resposta para uma pergunta similar no StackOverflow: [How to retrieve Enum name using the id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380243/how-to-retrieve-enum-name-using-the-id/15380351#15380351)

Comment: @MarcosVinicius só dá uma olhada na observação que eu coloquei

Comment: Beleza. Já fixei essas questões.
Ao utilizar
    case enumUpdateAction.NEW.getCodigo():
é apresentado o erro "constant expression required", sendo que tal enum é uma constante já definida. Tu sabe porque pode acontecer isso?

Comment: O `enumUpdateAction` é uma variável? Se for você deve fazer assim: `enum_type.NEW.getCodigo()`

Comment: No caso, enumUpdateAction é outro ENUM, praticamente identico ao enumType. Eu devia ter postado o enumUpdateAction, nem percebi que postei o errado. O enumUpdateAction tem  NEW(0), CHANGE(1), DELETE(2), DELETE_THRU(3), DELETE_FROM(4);. Estou tentando pegar o caractere 0, referente ao new, quando uso enum_type.NEW.getCodigo(), mas nao consigo. Aparece tal erro de constante expression required. Consegui ser claro? Haha

Comment: @MarcosVinicius tenta a segunda forma que eu coloquei ali

Comment: Cara, odeio votar negativo, ainda mais em um cara legal como você que eu gosto bastante. Mas o que você criou foi uma complicação bem grande que acaba mais desorientando e confundindo do que ajudando. Bastava usar os métodos `ordinal()` e `values()`. Além disso, dá para usar o `enum` diretamente no `switch`, não precisa ficar se matando para extrair `int`s.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado pelo feedback, porém a segunda parte do que você mencionou está na segunda parte da resposta. Não vejo como errada a primeira parte, mas tudo bem, ainda mais considerando que ele poderia, por exemplo utilizar um código que não fosse sequencial e tudo mais...

Comment: @MarcosVinicius para funcionar no case o atributo `codigo` no `enum` deve estar declarado como `final`. Dá uma olhada como ficou na resposta agora

Comment: Opa. Problema resolvido cara. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa a ignorância. Haha