# Elementos repetidos Linked List

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package TrabalhoFinal;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 *
 * @author rjs
 */
public class LinkedList < T > {

    private int count;
    private LinearNode < T > head,
    tail;

    /**
     * Creates an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        count = 0;
        head = tail = null;
    }

    public void add(T element) {

        LinearNode < T > newNode = new LinearNode < T > (element);
        LinearNode < T > oldHead = head;

        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            newNode.setNext(tail);
        } else {
            head = oldHead;
            oldHead.setNext(newNode);
        }
        count++;
    }



    public T remove(T element) {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("VAZIO");
        }
        boolean found = false;
        LinearNode < T > previous = null;
        LinearNode < T > current = head;

        while (current != null && !found) {
            if (element.equals(current.getElement())) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("VAZIO");
        }

        if (this.count == 1) {
            head = tail = null;
        } else if (current.equals(head)) {
            head = current.getNext();
        } else if (current.equals(tail)) {
            tail = previous;
            tail.setNext(null);
        } else {
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());
        }

        count--;

        return current.getElement();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (count == 0);
    }

    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean contains(T targetElement) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("VAZIO");
        }

        boolean found = false;
        Object result;

        LinearNode < T > current = head;

        while (current != null && !found) {
            if (targetElement.equals(current.getElement())) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object obj) {
        int index = 0;
        LinearNode < T > current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.equals(obj)) {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        LinearNode < T > current = head;
        String result = "";

        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("SEM CLIENTES");
        }
        while (current != null) {

            result = result + (current.getElement()).toString() + "\n";
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Como faço para percorrer o linked list e saber quantas vezes que um elemento é repetido
Exemplo:

> Pedro->A
>   Rui->B
>   Pedro->A

Pedro repete 2x

Comment: Qual é o código da classe `LinearNode`?

Answer (score 3):

Há várias coisas a se levar em conta no seu código. Não sei se o seu professor é bonzinho ou é carrasco ou o quanto ele perdoa ou pune o aluno por detalhes bobos. Assim sendo, vou falar de tudo que achar errado por mais bobo que seja.

1. Apague esse comentário:

   ```
   /*
    * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
    * and open the template in the editor.
    */
   ```

   Traduzindo:

   ```
   /*
    * Para alterar este modelo, escolha [o menu] Ferramentas | Modelos
    * e abra este modelo no editor.
    */
   ```

   Isso daí existe porque muitos projetos têm um o cabeçalho padrão para os arquivos do projeto, onde são colocadas mensagens de copyright, direitos autorais, confidencialidade, etc. No entanto, você não tem nada disso, pois você não configurou cabeçalho nenhum, e portanto o Netbeans cria esse modelo de cabeçalho contendo um texto que diz o que você deve fazer para configurar os cabeçalhos.

   Deixar esse cabeçalho padrão do Netbeans pedindo para você configurar o seu projeto é muito feio. Apenas apague isso de todos os arquivos do seu projeto ou escreva alguma outra coisa no comentário, tal como algo parecido com isso:

   ```
   /*
    * Este arquivo é parte do trabalho XXX da disciplina
    * YYY do curso ZZZ ministrada pelo professor
    * AAA na turma BBB do primeiro semestre de 2017.
    *
    * Aluno: CCC
    */
   ```
2. Declaração de pacote:

   ```
   package TrabalhoFinal;
   ```

   As regras de nomenclatura do Java dizem que nomes de pacotes devem estar em letras minúsculas.

   As regras de nomenclatura também dizem para você usar o nome do domínio em estrutura reversa, mas acredito que você não deva ter nenhum nome de domínio.
3. Os tipos genéricos:

   ```
   LinkedList < T >
   LinearNode < T >
   ```

   As regras de nomenclatura do Java dizem que não devem haver espaços entre o tipo base e o `<` dos genéricos, nem entre o `<` e o primeiro tipo genérico e nem entre o último tipo genérico e o `>`. Portanto, o adequado seria:

   ```
   LinkedList<T>
   LinearNode<T>
   ```

[**Veja mais sobre regras de nomenclatura nesta resposta.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132)

4. Ao instanciar classes genéricas, o compilador é (a partir do Java 7) capaz de em muitos casos adivinhar o tipo genérico do construtor, que pode ser omitido. Assim sendo, você pode trocar isso:

   ```
   LinearNode < T > newNode = new LinearNode < T > (element);
   ```

   Por isso:

   ```
   LinearNode <T> newNode = new LinearNode<>(element);
   ```

   Observe o `<>` no construtor. Esse é a chamada sintaxe do diamante. ([referência](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)).
5. **Nunca** coloque um `System.out.println` dentro do seu método `toString()`. Aliás, nunca faça no seu `toString()` qualquer coisa que possa causar um efeito colateral. Um dos motivos disso é que o Netbeans no mode debug chama o `toString()` em objetos que você está inspecionando no debug. Entretanto, se o método `toString()` puder causar efeitos colaterais (mesmo que um simples `System.out.println`), a saída do seu programa ficará bem confusa e não corresponderá a mesma saída que ele produziria em ambiente de produção. Além disso, é muito fácil fazer o método `toString()` ser chamado implicitamente pelo Java em diversos lugares.

   Além disso, a finalidade do método `toString()` é fornecer uma representação em formato de `String` do objeto. Isso significa que escrever qualquer coisa no console **não faz parte** da responsabilidade deste método. Logo, uma lógica que escreve algo no console dentro do `toString()` deve ser vista como uma intrusa indesejável e nociva a ser retirada do código.

   Também suspeito fortemente que o seu método `contains` segue uma lógica parecida e o `System.out.println` dentro dele é nocivo.
6. Vamos ver o seu método `indexOf`:

   ```
               if (current.equals(obj)) {
   ```

   Bem, `obj` é o elemento que você quer encontrar na lista, mas `current` é um nó da lista, e não um elemento. Assim sendo, esse teste do `equals` nunca será verdadeiro e o resultado sempre será -1. O que você queria é isso:

   ```
               if (current.getElement().equals(obj)) {
   ```

   Entretanto, se o elemento da lista for `null`, isso vai dar `NullPointerException`. Assim sendo, a solução é usar o método [`Objects.equals(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-):

   ```
       public int indexOf(Object obj) {
           int index = 0;
           LinearNode<T> current = head;

           while (current != null) {
               if (Objects.equals(current.getElement(), obj)) return index;
               index++;
               current = current.getNext();
           }

           return -1;
       }
   ```

   Se você preferir, pode usar um `for`:

   ```
       public int indexOf(Object obj) {
           int index = 0;

           for (LinearNode<T> current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
               if (Objects.equals(current.getElement(), obj)) return index;
               index++;
           }

           return -1;
       }
   ```
7. O seu método `contains` pode ser simplificado ao utilizar o `indexOf` dessa forma:

   ```
       public boolean contains(T targetElement) {
           return indexOf(targetElement) != -1;
       }
   ```

   Entretanto, se você não quiser usar o `indexOf` dentro do `contains`, podemos ver que a variável `found` não é necessária se você der `return true;` ao invés de `found = true;`, deixando um `return false;` no final do método. A variável `result` também não é necessária. O código ficaria assim:

   ```
       public boolean contains(T targetElement) {
           LinearNode<T> current = head;

           while (current != null) {
               if (Objects.equals(targetElement, current.getElement())) return true;
               current = current.getNext();
           }
           return false;
       }
   ```

   Note que quando a condição do `if` é verdadeira, o fluxo não tem como prosseguir na instrução seguinte ao corpo do `if` (o `current = current.getNext();`) por causa do `return`. Logo, não é necessário colocar-se o conteúdo seguinte ao corpo do `if` dentro de um bloco `else`.

   Você também pode optar por usar um `for`:

   ```
       public boolean contains(T targetElement) {
           for (LinearNode<T> current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
               if (Objects.equals(targetElement, current.getElement())) return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   ```
8. Evite concatenar muitas `String`s temporárias (o seu método `toString()` faz isso). Cada vez que você concatena uma `String`, uma nova `String` é criada na memória contendo cópias de cada pedaço concatenado, ao invés de serem alterados os pedaços já existentes. Isso é ineficiente, pois várias `String`s são criadas, copiadas para cima e para baixo e largadas na memória para serem coletadas como lixo. É mais eficiente usar o `StringBuilder` que é um objeto que sofre alterações na concatenação, ao invés de ser criado um novo objeto.

   Eis como fica o seu código revisado:

   ```
       @Override
       public String toString() {
           LinearNode<T> current = head;
           StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

           while (current != null) {
               result.append(current.getElement()).append('\n');
               current = current.getNext();
           }

           return result.toString();
       }
   ```

   Se preferir, você pode usar um `for`:

   ```
       @Override
       public String toString() {
           StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

           for (LinearNode<T> current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
               result.append(current.getElement()).append('\n');
           }

           return result.toString();
       }
   ```
9. Finalmente, com base na versão que fiz acima do método `contains` sem usar o `indexOf` e usando o `for`, podemos criar um método `countOccurrences`:

   ```
       public int countOccurrences(T targetElement) {
           int found = 0;
           for (LinearNode<T> current = head; current != null; current = current.getNext()) {
               if (Objects.equals(targetElement, current.getElement())) found++;
           }
           return found;
       }
   ```
10. Vejamos o seu método `add`:

    ```
            if (head == null) {
                head = newNode;
                newNode.setNext(tail);
    ```

    Se `head` é `null`, `tail` também será `null`, e portanto, você está fazendo `newNode.setNext(null);`, o que não vai fazer diferença uma vez que o `newNode` é recém-criado e o `next` dele já era `null`.

    ```
                head = oldHead;
    ```

    Neste ponto, `oldHead` já é uma referência para `head`. Logo, na prática isso não vai fazer nada.

    ```
                oldHead.setNext(newNode);
            }
    ```

    Você definiu que a cabeça antiga que apontava para um item `x`, agora aponta para um novo item `newNode`. Entretanto, isso não funciona e faz com que a sublista do item `x` em diante seja perdida, além de você não trocar a cabeça da lista. Você também nunca define o `tail` no método `add`. Assim sendo, sua lista nunca terá mais que dois elementos.

    Eis aqui uma forma de corrigir o método `add`. Como não sei se a ideia era acrescentar no começo ou no final, coloco os dois:

    ```
        public void addFirst(T element) {
            LinearNode<T> newNode = new LinearNode<>(element);
            newNode.setNext(head);
            head = newNode;
            if (tail == null) tail = newNode;
            count++;
        }

        public void addLast(T element) {
            LinearNode<T> newNode = new LinearNode<>(element);
            if (tail == null) {
                head = newNode;
            } else {
                tail.setNext(newNode);
            }
            tail = newNode;
            count++;
        }
    ```
11. Vejamos o seu método `remove`. Primeiro que ela tem um tipo de retorno que é o seguinte:

    ```
            return current.getElement();
    ```

    Ora, caso o elemento tenha sido encontrado, isso é o mesmo que:

    ```
            return element;
    ```

    Já no caso de o elemento não estar na lista, vai dar um `NullPointerException` no `} else if (current.equals(head)) {`. Usar o `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` arrumará os `else if`s, mas fará o `NullPointerException` ir para dentro do `else`. Isso me faz questionar qual é a utilidade do retorno deste método, já que ele é sempre o próprio parâmetro (caso não ocorra uma exceção). Assim sendo, penso que seria melhor que o retorno fosse `boolean`, onde `true` indica que o elemento foi encontrado e removido e `false` indica o contrário.

    Podemos começar a mexer no código ao melhorar a lógica do `while` que encontra o elemento desejado. Neste `while`, podemos eliminar a variável `found` ao usar o `break` assim:

    ```
            while (current != null) {
                if (element.equals(current.getElement())) break;
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            if (current == null) return false;
    ```

    Observe que neste caso, se ele iterar o `while` até o fim e não achar o elemento, o `if` logo em seguida termina o método sem que nada seja feito retornando `false`, e isso ocorre também no caso de a lista estar vazia. Uma vez que o `if` tendo a condição verdadeira executa o `break` e nunca continua o fluxo normalmente após o `if`, então o `else` não é necessário.

    Mais abaixo, na sequência de `if`s e `else if`s, o código está correto (agora que garantimos que o item foi encontrado). Entretanto, dá para melhorar ele ao usar o `==` ao invés do `equals`, uma vez que você está percorrendo os próprios nós da lista, e nunca cópias ou clones desses nós. No final, você dá um `return true;`. Por fim, os `System.out.println`s são intrusos a serem removidos do código.

    Assim fica o seu método revisado:

    ```
        public boolean remove(T element) {
            LinearNode<T> previous = null;
            LinearNode<T> current = head;

            while (current != null) {
                if (element.equals(current.getElement())) break;
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            if (current == null) return false;

            if (this.count == 1) {
                head = tail = null;
            } else if (current == head) {
                head = current.getNext();
            } else if (current == tail) {
                tail = previous;
                tail.setNext(null);
            } else {
                previous.setNext(current.getNext());
            }

            count--;

            return true;
        }
    ```

Comment: Sobre o item 2: tudo minúsculo? Em tosadas posições do nome? Se por acaso meu pacote _precisar de dois nomes_, coloco um `_`? Ou quebro em pacote e subpacote?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tudo minúsculo e junto sem separação nenhuma. Atualizei [a minha resposta para esclarecer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132). A lógica usada ao dividir em pacotes e subpacotes é a lógica de organização do projeto e não a lógica de organização da nomenclatura do projeto.

Comment: muito esclarecedor, obrigado