# Erro ao instanciar a classe

Tags: java

Estou tentando ler dados da classe `dados` no `Main` e ele me dá erro no meu *array*: `cadastro[i] = new dados();`

Classe dados:

```
class dados {
    private int numero;
    private String nome;
    private String sexo;

public dados(int nr,String n,String s, int idd,String m,String prv,String rl) //**********
    { 
    numero = nr;
    nome = n;
    sexo = s;
    idade = idd;
    moradia = m;
    provincia = prv;
    relegiao = rl;
    }

    public int getNumero(){
        return this.numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(int nr){
        this.numero = nr;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome; 
    }
    public void setNome(String n){
        this.nome = n;
    }

    public String getSexo(){
        return sexo;
    }
    public void setSexo(String s){ 
        this.sexo = s;
    }
```

classe main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
          dados cadastro[] = new dados[100];
          for(int i = 0; i< cadastro.length; i++){

             cadastro[i] = new dados(); //esta dando erro nessa linha

              cadastro[i].getNumero(); // Recuperando o numero
                                cadastro[i].setNumero(Integer.parseInt(//habilitando a insercao
                                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Atribua um Numero ao Cidadao")));//Atribuindo um valor

                                cadastro[i].getNome();// Recuperando o nome
                                cadastro[i].setNome( //habilitando a insercao
                                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                        ("Digite o Nome Completo do Cidadao"));//Atribuindo um valor ao nome
```

Comment: Me desculpe eu falhei é sim java

Comment: Mais sobre convenções da linguagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132

Answer (score 8):

O problema é que você criou um construtor que recebe argumentos para iniciar as propriedades da classe, mas está tentando iniciar um objeto desta classe sem passar nenhum. Ou você cria um construtor sem argumentos alternativo ou inicie corretamente a classe já passando todos os valores que definiu no construtor.

Outra coisa é sempre seguir a [convenção do java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) corretamente, onde **nomes de classes sempre devem iniciar com letra maiúscula**.

Sem mexer muito no código, a solução mais simples seria a criação do construtor sem parâmetros, conforme abaixo:

```
class Dados {
    private int numero;
    private String nome;
    private String sexo;

public Dados(){}

public Dados(int nr,String n,String s, int idd,String m,String prv,String rl) //**********
    { 
    numero = nr;
    nome = n;
    sexo = s;
    idade = idd;
    moradia = m;
    provincia = prv;
    relegiao = rl;
    }

    public int getNumero(){
        return this.numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(int nr){
        this.numero = nr;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome; 
    }
    public void setNome(String n){
        this.nome = n;
    }

    public String getSexo(){
        return sexo;
    }
    public void setSexo(String s){ 
        this.sexo = s;
    }
```

Comment: Certo! Entendido....

Comment: Muito Obrigado Articuno, consegui resolver o erro

Comment: @victorpereira se a resposta lhe ajudou, você pode aceita-la como certa clicando no `v` ao lado. :)

Comment: Sinceramente, quando vi a classe minúscula parei de ler! Não me apego muito nas teorias da OO que alguns ficam se matando por aí em discussão nos fóruns, mas é provável que o cara nem leu, pelo menos, os conceitos da OO, principalmente em relação a linguagem java.