# Nome, Sobrenome, Idade JAVA POO

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Eu tenho de fazer isso: Modelo computacionalmente o problema de obter o nome completo, a idade, a
idade em meses a partir do nome, sobrenome e ano de nascimento de uma
pessoa. Eu fiz assim mas não ta dando certo, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
public class Pessoa

{
   public String nome;
   public String sobrenome;
   public int AnoDeNascimento;

   public String setNome (String newNome)
   {
       this.nome = newNome;
   }

   public String getNome () 
   {
       return nome;
   }

   public String Sobrenome (String newSobrenome)
   {
       this.sobrenome = newSobrenome;
   }

   public String getSobrenome ()
   {
       return sobrenome;
   }

   public int setAnoDeNascimento (int anonas)
   {
       this.AnoDeNascimento = anonas;
   }

   public String getNomeCompleto () 
   {
       return nome + sobrenome; 
   }
}
```

Comment: O que "não tá dando certo"?

Comment: O bluej fica reclamando a respeito de public String dos metódos setNome, 
   e setAnoDeNascimento

Comment: Reclamando é muito geral, você precisa detalhar isso.

Comment: Porque a assinatura dos dois métodos exigem retorno mas você não retorna nada. Metodos setters normalmente não retornam nada, são void;

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado me ajudou bastante

Comment: Acho que alguém já te falou que não é para se usar atributos públicos, né?

Comment: @Articuno Eu poderia postar uma resposta ao nosso amigo dizendo isso, mas como você viu primeiro, acho melhor você ir em frente com isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se quiser responder com algo mais elaborado, pode responder, eu sou péssimo em elaborar respostas teóricas ou canônicas, como essa pergunta pede.

Comment: @Articuno Feito.

Answer (score 0):

Veja esses dois métodos:

```
  public String setNome (String newNome)
  {
      this.nome = newNome;
  }
```

E:

```
  public String Sobrenome (String newSobrenome)
  {
      this.sobrenome = newSobrenome;
  }
```

Ambos declaram retornar `String`, mas não têm nenhuma instrução do tipo `return`. O compilador não vai gostar disso e vai reclamar que falta o `return`. O BlueJ vai te mostrar esse erro que ele pega do compilador.

O retorno de ambos deveria ser `void`. Além disso, o método para definir o seobrenome deveria se chamar `setSobrenome`, e não apenas `Sobrenome`.

O seu código também não segue bem as [convenções da linguagem Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132) (mesmo se considerar que o que ocorre na verdade é que há algumas convenções não-oficiais competindo entre si). Em especial, o campo `AnoDeNascimento` deveria se chamar `anoDeNascimento`, começando com letra minúscula.

Além disso, o nome do parâmetro no método `setAnoDeNascimento` poderia ser `newAnoDeNascimento`, ao invés de `anonas`. O motivo é que abreviar palavras comendo letras do nome é uma péssima prática de programação e tende a deixar os programas muito difíceis de serem compreendidos. Aliás, para evitar misturar palavras em inglês com palavras em português em um mesmo nome, poderíamos chamar de `novoAnoDeNascimento`. Os demais parâmetros dos setters seriam `novoNome` e `novoSobrenome`. Quanto a misturar português e inglês ao colocar-se os prefixos `get` e `set`, isso daí é melhor ser tolerado porque muitas ferramentas buscam métodos com os prefixos `get` e `set` para identificar as propriedades dos seus objetos, e ao alterar esses prefixos, essas ferramentas não funcionarão com a sua classe (o que é outro motivo para chamar o seu método para definir o sobrenome de `setSobrenome`).

Um outro detalhe, é que em nenhuma convenção formatação de código amplamente utilizada, usa-se espaço entre o nome do método e o `(` dos parâmetros que o segue. A linha em branco entre a declaração da classe e o `{` também não é algo que esteja de acordo com qualquer convenção de formatação de código.

Note também que no seu método `getNomeCompleto()`, é uma boa ideia acrescentar um espaço entre o nome e o sobrenome.

Finalmente, você já deve ter visto em vários locais que manter atributos/campos públicos é considerado uma péssima prática de programação, e o motivo de você estar usando getters e setters tem diretamente a ver com isso. Assim sendo, eles devem ser privados.

Corrigindo-se esses detalhes, o seu código fica assim:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private int anoDeNascimento;

    public void setNome(String novoNome)
    {
        this.nome = novoNome;
    }

    public String getNome() 
    {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String novoSobrenome)
    {
        this.sobrenome = novoSobrenome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome()
    {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public int setAnoDeNascimento(int novoAnoDeNascimento)
    {
        this.anoDeNascimento = novoAnoDeNascimento;
    }

    public String getNomeCompleto() 
    {
        return nome + " " + sobrenome;
    }
}
```