# Retorno de método em Java

Tags: java

Não conheço nada de Java. Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o valor do retorno da variável `dv` que está dentro do método `Base10()` e usá-lo no `main`. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
public class Boleto {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String codBarras = "23793.44308.90010.000041.33001.250001.3.52830000008091";        

}
    public class Barra{
        public int Base10(String num){  
            //variáveis de instancia
            int soma = 0;
            int resto = 0;
            int dv = 0;
            String[] numeros = new String[num.length()+1];
            int multiplicador = 2;
            String aux;
            String aux2;
            String aux3;

            for (int i = num.length(); i > 0; i--) {            
                //Multiplica da direita pra esquerda, alternando os algarismos 2 e 1
                if(multiplicador%2 == 0){
                    // pega cada numero isoladamente  
                    numeros[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(num.substring(i-1,i))*2);
                    multiplicador = 1;
                }else{
                    numeros[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(num.substring(i-1,i))*1);
                    multiplicador = 2;
                }
            }  
            // Realiza a soma dos campos de acordo com a regra
            for(int i = (numeros.length-1); i > 0; i--){
                aux = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(numeros[i]));
                if(aux.length()>1){
                    aux2 = aux.substring(0,aux.length()-1);             
                    aux3 = aux.substring(aux.length()-1,aux.length());
                    numeros[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(aux2) + Integer.valueOf(aux3));             
                }
                else{
                    numeros[i] = aux;           
                }
            }
            //Realiza a soma de todos os elementos do array e calcula o digito verificador
            //na base 10 de acordo com a regra.     
            for(int i = numeros.length; i > 0 ; i--){
                if(numeros[i-1] != null){
                    soma += Integer.valueOf(numeros[i-1]);
                }
            }
            resto = soma%10;
            dv = 10 - resto;
            //retorna o digito verificador

            return dv;
        } 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Vi que você editou a pergunta. Por causa disso, editei a [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268799/132) também.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta fazer isso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String codBarras = "23793.44308.90010.000041.33001.250001.3.52830000008091";        
    String codBarrasLimpo = codBarras.replace(".", "");
    int dv = Base10(codBarrasLimpo);
    System.out.println(dv);
}
```

A saída é 6.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Hzpdgl)

---

Como a pergunta foi editada, aqui vão mais algumas informações:

O `String codBarrasLimpo = codBarras.replace(".", "");` serve para retirar os pontos da `String`. O código do método `Base10` não sabe lidar com eles, e por isso é importante retirá-los antes de calcular a base 10. A `String` original (`codBarras`) é preservada, o que significa que essa operação não é destrutiva, pois uma outra `String` (a `codBarrasLimpo`) sem os pontos é criada sem que a antiga (`codBarras`) seja danificada.

O código acima é possível se o método `Base10` for estático e estando na mesma classe.

Se ele estiver em outra classe, continuando a ser estático, então você usa isso:

```
int dv = Barra.Base10(codBarrasLimpo);
```

Se ele não for estático, você vai precisar de uma instância da classe que o envolve (no caso `Barra`):

```
Barra b = new Barra();
int dv = b.Base10(codBarrasLimpo);
```

Entretanto, uma instância de `Barra` não representa nada. O método `Base10` não necessita de nenhuma instância para operar. Então, a menos que você reorganize as coisas de alguma outra forma, o melhor seria deixar o método `Base10` estático mesmo.

Um outro porém é que o método devia ser chamado `base10`. A convenção de nomenclatura do Java dita que nomes de métodos devem/deveriam ser iniciados com letra minúscula. Veja mais sobre isso [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132).

Comment: Obrigado man, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Chama o metodo e atribua ele à uma variavel:

```
x = Base10(String num)
```

Logo 'x' receberá o retorno do metodo;

Comment: Base10 é estático, não é necessário criar um objeto

Comment: Nao vi essa parte

Comment: @Victor Editei o código, na verdade o método Base10 naõ é estático.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String codBarras = "23793.44308.90010.000041.33001.250001.3.52830000008091";        
         int dv = Base10(codBarras){ 
}
```