# Qual o problema com esses algoritmos de hash?

Tags: java, hash

Pesquisei vários algoritmos de hash, e encontrei alguns de exemplo no SOen, mas eles estão retornando hashes diferentes para o mesmo arquivo:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.DigestInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class ObterHash {

    private static String algoritmo = "SHA-256";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        File arq = new File("C:\\img.jpg");
        System.out.println(toHex(gerarHash1(arq)));
        System.out.println(toHex(gerarHash2(arq)));
        System.out.println(toHex(gerarHash3(arq)));
    }

    // Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304310/7711016
    public static byte[] gerarHash1(File arq) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        DigestInputStream shaStream = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(arq),
                MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo));
        // VERY IMPORTANT: read from final stream since it's FilterInputStream
        byte[] shaDigest = shaStream.getMessageDigest().digest();
        shaStream.close();
        return shaDigest;
    }

    // Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231444/7711016
    public static byte[] gerarHash2(File arq) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(arq.toPath());
        byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo).digest(b);
        return hash;
    }

    // Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/304275/7711016
    public static byte[] gerarHash3(File arq) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(arq);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo);
        int numRead;

        do {
            numRead = fis.read(buffer);
            if (numRead > 0) {
                complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
        } while (numRead != -1);

        fis.close();
        return complete.digest();
    }

    private static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            ret.append(String.format("%02X", (bytes[i] & 0xFF)));
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
}
```

Quando executado, tive essa saída (um hashcode em cada linha):

> E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855
>   010F60D2927A35D0235490136EF9F4953B7EE453073794BCAF153D20A64544EA
>   010F60D2927A35D0235490136EF9F4953B7EE453073794BCAF153D20A64544EA

Veja que o hash gerado por `gerarHash2()` e `gerarHash3()` são iguais entre si, mas diferentes do `gerarHash1()`. Por quê? É o algoritmo de `gerarHash1()` que está errado? Se sim, qual é o erro nele?

Comment: Sua pergunta tem +1/-1. O +1 é meu. Não sei o porquê do -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos ver o código do construtor de `DigestInputStream`:

```
    /**
     * Creates a digest input stream, using the specified input stream
     * and message digest.
     *
     * @param stream the input stream.
     *
     * @param digest the message digest to associate with this stream.
     */
    public DigestInputStream(InputStream stream, MessageDigest digest) {
        super(stream);
        setMessageDigest(digest);
    }
```

Ele chama o construtor da superclasse:

```
    /**
     * Creates a <code>FilterInputStream</code>
     * by assigning the  argument <code>in</code>
     * to the field <code>this.in</code> so as
     * to remember it for later use.
     *
     * @param   in   the underlying input stream, or <code>null</code> if
     *          this instance is to be created without an underlying stream.
     */
    protected FilterInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }
```

E também chama o setter:

```
    /**
     * Associates the specified message digest with this stream.
     *
     * @param digest the message digest to be associated with this stream.
     * @see #getMessageDigest()
     */
    public void setMessageDigest(MessageDigest digest) {
        this.digest = digest;
    }
```

Em seguida, você chama o método `getMessageDigest()`:

```
    /**
     * Returns the message digest associated with this stream.
     *
     * @return the message digest associated with this stream.
     * @see #setMessageDigest(java.security.MessageDigest)
     */
    public MessageDigest getMessageDigest() {
        return digest;
    }
```

Observe que em lugar nenhum, o `DigestInputStream` está sendo lido ou está lendo os bytes do arquivo do `FileInputStream` passado a ele. Assim, quando você chama o método `digest()`, o `MessageDigest` não conhece o conteúdo do arquivo e está vazio. Assim sendo, o hash gerado é o mesmo hash disso:

```
System.out.println(toHex(MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo).digest()));
```

O que deu errado? Notemos esse comentário:

```
        // VERY IMPORTANT: read from final stream since it's FilterInputStream
```

Ele está dizendo justamente que você tem que ler o conteúdo do último stream produzido, o que na [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304310/7711016) fazia todo o sentido já que lá ele está envelopando os streams uns nos outros consecutivamente, coisa que não é o seu caso. Logo, basta substituir esse comentário por isso:

```
shaStream.readAllBytes();
```

Ao acrescentar isso, o hash gerado é o mesmo dos outros dois métodos. Desse modo, o seu método `gerarHash1` pode ser reescrito assim:

```
    // Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304310/7711016
    public static byte[] gerarHash1(File arq) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        try (DigestInputStream shaStream = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(arq),
                MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo))) {
            shaStream.readAllBytes();
            return shaStream.getMessageDigest().digest();
        }
    }
```

Observe que essa nessa forma estou usando o [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132). No método `gerarHash3`, recomendo que você também use o *try-with-resources*. Também recomendo colocar o modificador `final` no campo `algoritmo` e renomeá-lo para `ALGORITMO` para ficar de acordo com [as convenções da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/132).

Nota: O [método `readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) só está disponível a partir do Java 9. Nas versões anteriores, você precisará utilizar alguma outra coisa no lugar (um laço `while` provavelmente) para simular o seu comportamento.