# Qual o erro nesse código?

Tags: java

Não compreendi qual o erro do código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questao4 {
   public static void main (String[] args){
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      double Altura, Fixo, Fixo2, PesoIdeal, Resultado1;

      Altura = 1,73; //Chute
      Fixo = 72,7;
      Fixo2 = 58;

      Resultado1 = Altura * Fixo;
      PesoIdeal = Resultado1 - Fixo2;

      System.out.print("Peso Ideal = " + PesoIdeal);
   }
}
```

Ao compilar, os seguintes erros foram detectados:

> ```
> Questao4.java:6: error: ';' expected
>     Altura = 1,73; //Chute
> Questao4.java:7: error: ';' expected
>     Fixo = 72,7;
> ```

Comment: No java. Os números double tem que ser ponto (ex. 1.73) e não vírgula (1,73)

Comment: Achei os votos negativos exagerados, acho que o comentário de @adventistaam resolvem o problema

Comment: Antes da edicao, os votos sao merecidos sim. Motivo de fechamento foi equivocado, acho que isso é mais erro de digitacao.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Números em ponto flutuante são separados com um ponto decimal, não com uma vírgula decimal.

Além disso, [nomes de variáveis deveriam começar com letras minúsculas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/132), embora o compilador não vá reclamar disso, é apenas uma convenção de código.

Seu código corrigido:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questao4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double altura = 1.73; //Chute
        double fixo = 72.7;
        double fixo2 = 58;

        double resultado1 = altura * fixo;
        double pesoIdeal = resultado1 - fixo2;

        System.out.print("Peso Ideal = " + pesoIdeal);
    }
}
```