# Verificar se uma expressão está bem formada

Tags: c, stack

Estava tentando fazer um programa que verifica se uma expressão é bem formada.

Algo do tipo `{[()()]}` é bem formado enquanto que algo do tipo `{{())({]` não é.

Implementei uma bilbioteca "pilha.c" do qual eu tiro algumas funções do programa que deixo abaixo.

Basicamente se o caractere lido for de "abertura" ele é empilhado na pilha.
Ao ler um caractere de "fechamento" ele verifica se é o caractere que corresponde ao de abertura no topo da pilha; se for, ele desempilha o caractere de leitura e prossegue a leitura. Se não a expressão é má formada.
Alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado aí?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pilha.h"

int bemFormada(char v[]) {
    apontaPilha p = criaPilha(strlen(v) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++)
        if (v[i] != '{' || v[i] != '}' || v[i] != '[' || v[i] != ']' || v[i] != '(' || v[i] != ')')
            v[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++)
        printf("%d", v[i]);

    while (i < strlen(v) && v[i] != 0) {
        c = v[i];
        if (c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(') {
            empilha(p, c);
        }
        else {
            if(pilhaVazia(p))
                return 0;
            else if ((c == '}' && eleTopo(p) == '{') || (c == ']' && eleTopo(p) == '[') || (c == ')' && eleTopo(p) == '('))
                c = desempilha(p);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (!pilhaVazia(0)) {
        destroiPilha(p);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char v[100], c;
    int i;

    printf("Informe a sequencia: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        c = scanf("%s", v);
    }

    if (bemFormada(v))
        printf("\nBem formada!\n");
    else
        printf("\nMal formada!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

***--- Pilha.c ---***

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "pilha.h"

    #define tipoDaPilha int
    typedef struct pilha Pilha;

    typedef Pilha * apontaPilha;

   apontaPilha criaPilha(int tamanho);

    struct pilha {
        char *v; /*mudar dependendo do tipo de dado usado*/
        int topo;
        int tamanho;
    };

apontaPilha criaPilha(int tamanho) {
    apontaPilha p = malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->v = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(Pilha));
    p->topo = 0;
    p->tamanho = tamanho;

    return p;
}

tipoDaPilha pilhaCheia(Pilha *p) {
    if (p->topo > p->tamanho)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

tipoDaPilha pilhaVazia(Pilha *p) {
    return (p->topo == 0);
}

void empilha(Pilha *p, char elemento) {
    if (!pilhaCheia(p)) {
        p->v[p->topo] = elemento;
        p->topo++;
    }
    else
        printf("Pilha cheia!\n");
}

char desempilha(Pilha *p) {
    if (!pilhaVazia(p)) {
        p->topo--;
        return p->v[p->topo];
    }
    else
        return '\0';
}

tipoDaPilha topo(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo;
}

char eleTopo(Pilha *p) {
    return p->v[p->topo - 1];
}

void destroiPilha(Pilha *p) {
    free(p->v);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! A sua pergunta é “Alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado aí?”. Para ajudar a responder a sua pergunta, nos informe como você viu que há algo errado: erros de compilação; resultados inesperados (para qual entrada?) — podem ser simples erros de lógica; fechamentos repentinos — podem ser erros no uso de alocação de memória e isso pode estar na sua biblioteca e não no código mostrado...

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta e acrescentar o código das funções `empilha`, `desempilha`, `criaPilha`, `destroiPilha` e `pilhaVazia`?

Comment: Qual o erro que dá? A logica parece-me bem, provavelmente poderiamos fazer de outra forma, mas usar a pilha dessa forma parece-me resultar

Comment: @VictorStafusa essas funçoes provavelmente são bibliotecas que não se deve de mexer, apenas precisamos de saber o que elas fazem.

Comment: Ok, vou deixar a pilha.c

Comment: @LucasLopes Mas essa biblioteca está bem feita? Ou é preciso detetar erros nisso?

Comment: Ela esta funcionando bem aparentemente. Tem uns typedefs a mais ali porque estava testando uma outra coisa num outro programa. Mas não interfere no funcionamento dessa.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++)
        if (v[i] != '{' || v[i] != '}' || v[i] != '[' || v[i] != ']' || v[i] != '(' || v[i] != ')')
            v[i] = 0;` Para que serve esse pedaço de codigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa que me chamou a atenção foi isso:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++)
        if (v[i] != '{' || v[i] != '}' || v[i] != '[' || v[i] != ']' || v[i] != '(' || v[i] != ')')
            v[i] = 0;
```

Isso daí está danificando a string dada como entrada, truncando-a ao colocar um terminador nulo no meio dela. Não recomendo fazer isso. Não parece ter sentido. Talvez seria melhor ignorar os símbolos que não estejam no grupo `()[]{}` ao invés de tentar apagá-los.

Vamos ver esta parte:

```
    else {
        if(pilhaVazia(p))
            return 0;
        else if ((c == '}' && eleTopo(p) == '{') || (c == ']' && eleTopo(p) == '[') || (c == ')' && eleTopo(p) == '('))
            c = desempilha(p);
    }
    i++;
```

Para entender melhor, vamos reescrever assim:

```
    else {
        if (pilhaVazia(p)) return 0;
        char t = eleTopo(p);
        else if ((c == '}' && t == '{') || (c == ']' && t == '[') || (c == ')' && t == '(')) {
            c = desempilha(p);
        }
    }
    i++;
```

Bem, aqui você desempilha se você tiver encontrado o símbolo que fecha correspondente ao que abriu. Mas, e se tiver fechando algo que não foi aberto? Nesse caso, você não faz nada, e isso é uma das coisas que está errada. Além disso, você atribui o símbolo desempilhado a variável `c`, mas o valor a ela atribuído nunca será utilizado, pois na próxima iteração do `while` o `c = v[i];` vai sobrescrever esse valor.

Na verdade, o que você deveria fazer era se encontrar um `)]}`, desempilhar **sempre** o topo da pilha (que contém a abertura) e verificar se o fechamento corresponde a abertura.

O `if (pilhaVazia(0))` também é suspeito. Não era para ser um `p` no lugar do `0`?

E também tem isso:

```
criaPilha(strlen(v) * sizeof(char))
```

Esse `sizeof(char)` não tem sentido estar aí. O parâmetro é a quantidade de elementos a ser considerados na pilha, o tamanho de cada elemento não interessa pois a sua implementação da pilha já lida com isso.

Também não acho isso legal:

```
typedef Pilha * apontaPilha;
```

Isso não vai prejudicar o seu programa, mas não acho que vai ajudar também. Esse tipo de coisa mascara os seus tipos e é confuso. Sugiro usar apenas `Pilha *` diretamente.

Isso daqui também é estranho:

```
#define tipoDaPilha int
```

Isso também não ajuda em nada o seu código. Ainda mais considerando que o retorno das funções `pilhaCheia` e `pilhaVazia` é desse tipo, sendo que o ideal seria usar tipo booleano. Alterando os tipos de retorno dessas funções para `int` ou para `bool`, essa define quase que perde o propósito de existir. Só fica na função `topo`, que deveria na verdade se chamar `tamanhoPilha` e o retorno dela não tem nada a ver com o tipo da pilha, é na verdade um número inteiro e portanto deveria ser `int`.

Na verdade, o tipo da pilha era para ser `char`, e não `int`. Pois nela, você está empilhando caracteres. Assim sendo, o tipo deveria estar nos lugares onde há `char`, ou seja, `empilha`, `desempilha`, `eleTopo` e no campo `v` do `struct`.

Com base nisso, essa alocação está errada:

```
malloc(tamanho * sizeof(Pilha));
```

O certo seria `sizeof(char)`. Ou então `sizeof(tipoDaPilha)`. Você está alocando memória suficiente para guardar um número de elementos, então você deveria multiplicar o número de elementos pelo tamanho de cada elemento.

No mais, o seu `pilha.c` me parece correto.

O seu `main` também não está certo:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    c = scanf("%s", v);
}
```

Você deveria ou ler 100 caracteres e colocá-los numa string ou então ler uma string com até 100 caracteres. Esse `for` não faz nem uma coisa nem outra, ele está lendo 100 strings diferentes sem se importar com o tamanho e colocando todas elas no mesmo lugar umas por cima das outras. O que você queria era isso:

```
scanf("%99s", v);
```

Esse 99 é o tamanho máximo da string, sem contar com o terminador nulo. O terminador nulo deve caber dentro das 100 posições que você reservou para o vetor, logo seu limite é de 99 caracteres mais o terminador nulo.

Reestruturei o seu código. Nele estou garantindo que a string original nunca é alterada, uso uma variável `tamanho` para evitar usar `strlen` mais de uma vez e garanto que os caracteres que não são `()[]{}` são pulados e uso um `for` no lugar do `while`. Também é importante chamar o `destroiPilha(p)` antes de **todos** os `return`s. Ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pilha.h"

int bemFormada(char v[]) {
    int tamanho = strlen(v);
    Pilha *p = criaPilha(tamanho);

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        char c = v[i];
        if (c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(') {
            empilha(p, c);
        } else if (c == '}' || c == ']' || c == ')') {
            if (pilhaVazia(p)) {
                destroiPilha(p);
                return 0;
            }
            char t = desempilha(p);
            if ((c == '}' && t != '{') || (c == ']' && t != '[') || (c == ')' && t != '(')) {
                destroiPilha(p);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int vazio = pilhaVazia(p);
    destroiPilha(p);
    return vazio;
}

int main() {
    char v[100];

    printf("Informe a sequencia: ");
    scanf("%99s", v);

    if (bemFormada(v)) {
        printf("\nBem formada!\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nMal formada!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note que no código acima, as funções `topo` e `eleTopo` não precisam mais ser utilizadas.

Seu `pilha.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pilha.h"

#define tipoDaPilha char

typedef struct pilha {
    tipoDaPilha *v; /*mudar dependendo do tipo de dado usado*/
    int topo;
    int tamanho;
} Pilha;

Pilha *criaPilha(int tamanho) {
    apontaPilha p = malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->v = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(tipoDaPilha ));
    p->topo = 0;
    p->tamanho = tamanho;

    return p;
}

int pilhaCheia(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo > p->tamanho;
}

int pilhaVazia(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo == 0;
}

void empilha(Pilha *p, tipoDaPilha elemento) {
    if (!pilhaCheia(p)) {
        p->v[p->topo] = elemento;
        p->topo++;
    } else {
        printf("Pilha cheia!\n");
    }
}

tipoDaPilha desempilha(Pilha *p) {
    if (!pilhaVazia(p)) {
        p->topo--;
        return p->v[p->topo];
    } else {
        return '\0';
    }
}

int tamanho(Pilha *p) {
    return p->topo;
}

tipoDaPilha elementoTopo(Pilha *p) {
    return p->v[p->topo - 1];
}

void destroiPilha(Pilha *p) {
    free(p->v);
    free(p);
}
```

Ah, finalmente recomendo sempre usar as chaves `{}` nos laços `for`, `while` e em `else`s e `if`s com várias linhas. Explico a razão disso no meio [desta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132) na seção "*Chaves após `if`, `else`, `while` e `for`*". Embora essa resposta seja sobre Java especificamente, grande parte dela (mas nem tudo) também se aplica ao C.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários! 
Irei revisar a implementação da pilha e refazer o programa do zero.

Comment: @LucasLopes Não precisa refazer do zero. Os erros não eram muitos e eu já postei o código acima. Ah, e se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Comment: @LucasLopes Caso precise de uma biblioteca para guiar recomendo o meu [GitHub](https://github.com/fabiouds/FEUP/tree/master/PROG2/BIBLIOTECAS_PROG) as bibliotecas estão super bem feitas e todas comentadas (no .h), está pronto a ser utilizado