# Java Spring Boot - Ler um arquivo da pasta Resources dentro de um .jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pentaho

Eu estou escrevendo uma classe que irá ler um ETL Pentaho Kettle (transformação). Eu coloquei o arquivo que a classe irá ler na pasta Resources / KTR.

Mas quando eu tento executar o código como uma aplicação java (java -jar), obtenho um erro dizendo que o arquivo não existe.

Entretanto, ele está tentando ler o arquivo do disco local e não de dentro do meu .jar.

Como eu leio o arquivo de dentro do .jar?

Eu estou usando o  Spring Boot 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT e o Java 1.8.

```
public class run_tranform {

 public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
 String file="src/main/resources/KTR/transformation.ktr";

    try {
        KettleEnvironment.init();
        //TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(file.getPath());
        TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(file);
        Trans trans = new Trans( metaData );
        trans.execute( null );
        trans.waitUntilFinished();
        if ( trans.getErrors() > 0 ) {
            System.out.print( "Error Executing transformation" );
        }
    } catch( KettleException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Ei, Diego, não sei se você percebeu, mas este site está em português. Assim sendo, você deveria ter postado em português. Já traduzi a sua pergunta para você.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar, eu sugiro a você, seguir as [convenções da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132) e ao invés de nomear a sua classe como `run_transform`, nomeá-la como `RunTransform`.

Você pode obter um `InputStream` para o recurso dentro do JAR ao usar o [método `getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) com a [sintaxe do *try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) assim:

```
String resource = "/KTR/transformation.ktr";
try (InputStream is = RunTransform.class.getResourceAsStream(resource)) {
    // ...
}
```

No entanto, a [classe `TransMeta`](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java) não tem um construtor que recebe apenas um `InputStream` ou apenas um `Reader` em substituição a esse que recebe um `File`. Há apenas um construtor com os parâmetros [`TransMeta(InputStream, Repository, boolean, VariableSpace, OverwritePrompter)`](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java#L2367):

> ```
>     public TransMeta(InputStream xmlStream, Repository rep, boolean setInternalVariables, VariableSpace parentVariableSpace, OverwritePrompter prompter ) throws KettleXMLException
>    {
>       loadXML( XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(xmlStream, null, false, false), rep, setInternalVariables, parentVariableSpace, prompter);
>    }
> ```

Assim, sendo, vamos dar uma olhadinha no [construtor que você está usando, que recebe um `File`](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java#L2259):

> ```
>    public TransMeta(String fname) throws KettleXMLException
>    {
>        this(fname, true);
>    }
> ```

Isso chama um [outro construtor](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java#L2284):

> ```
>     public TransMeta(String fname, boolean setInternalVariables) throws KettleXMLException
>    {
>        this(fname, null, setInternalVariables);
>    }
> ```

Que chama [mais outro](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java#L2307):

> ```
>     public TransMeta(String fname, Repository rep, boolean setInternalVariables ) throws KettleXMLException
>    {
>       this(fname, rep, setInternalVariables, null);
>    }
> ```

Que chama [ainda outro](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java#L2320):

> ```
>     public TransMeta(String fname, Repository rep, boolean setInternalVariables, VariableSpace parentVariableSpace ) throws KettleXMLException
>    {
>       this(fname, rep, setInternalVariables, parentVariableSpace, null);
>    }
> ```

[Mais um](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/TransMeta.java#L2334):

> ```
>    public TransMeta(String fname, Repository rep, boolean setInternalVariables, VariableSpace parentVariableSpace, OverwritePrompter prompter ) throws KettleXMLException
>    {
>        // ... Um monte de coisas aqui
>    }
> ```

Nesse último construtor, a assinatura é quase a mesma do construtor desejado, com a diferença que o primeiro parâmetro é `String` ao invés de `InputStream`. Tanto no construtor que você chama quanto no desejado, há uma chamada a um método `loadXML`. No construto desejado, como o primeiro parâmetro à esse método, temos isso:

> ```
> XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(xmlStream, null, false, false)
> ```

[Esse método](https://github.com/cwarden/kettle/blob/master/src-core/org/pentaho/di/core/xml/XMLHandler.java#L496) retorna um `Document`. Já o construtor com `String` carrega o `Document` do arquivo e o utiliza para chamar o método `loadXML`.

Conclui-se então que você tem que substituir isso:

```
TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(file);
```

Por isso:

```
TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(is, null, true, null, null);
```

Seu código resultante fica esse:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;

public class RunTransform {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String resource = "/KTR/transformation.ktr";
        try (InputStream is = RunTransform.class.getResourceAsStream(resource)) {
            KettleEnvironment.init();
            TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta(is, null, true, null, null);
            Trans trans = new Trans(metaData);
            trans.execute(null);
            trans.waitUntilFinished();
            if (trans.getErrors() > 0) {
                System.out.print("Error Executing transformation");
            }
        } catch (KettleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```