# Fazer busca em profundidade usando uma pilha

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, stack, grafo

Estou tentando fazer uma busca em profundidade usando uma pilha, mas está dando erro em um `if` e não sei o motivo.

```
   package Grafos;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Grafo {
    LinkedList<Integer> Arestas [];
    int n;
    int qtd_Arestas = 0;
    public Grafo(int n){
        this.n = n;
        Arestas = new LinkedList[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            Arestas[i] = new LinkedList();
    }
    public void Adiciona_aresta(int origem, int destino){
        Arestas[origem].add(destino);
        qtd_Arestas++;
    }
    public int DFS(int S, boolean visited[], int contador){
        visited[S] = true;
        ListIterator<Integer> v = Arestas[S].listIterator();
        while(v.hasNext()) {
            n = v.next();
            System.out.println(S + ">>" + n);
            if(!visited[n]){
                contador = DFS(n,visited,contador+1);
            }
        }
        return contador+1;

    }
    public void DFS_ini(int S){
        boolean Visitados[] = new boolean [n];
        int contador = 0;
        int b = DFS(S,Visitados,contador);
        System.out.println("____________________________________________________");
    }

    public void Pilha_DFS(int S) {
        boolean visitados [] = new boolean [n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
            visitados[i] = false;
        }
        int gatilho;
        int topo;
        visitados[S] = true;
        Stack pilha = new Stack();
        pilha.push(S);
        while(!pilha.isEmpty()){
            topo = (int) pilha.firstElement();
            if(Arestas[S].isEmpty()){
                gatilho = 1;
                break;
            }
            for(int linha : Arestas[S]) {
                if(visitados[linha] == false){//Erro aqui
                    System.out.println(S + ">>" + linha);
                    visitados[linha] = true;
                    pilha.add(linha);
                    S = linha;
                }else if(visitados[topo] == true){
                    pilha.remove(topo);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Erro apresentado:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Grafos.Grafo.Pilha_DFS(Grafo.java:55)
    at Grafos.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `Arestas`? O código dá a entender que é algo como `List<Integer>[]`, mas tenho algumas dúvidas.

Comment: `Stack` é `java.util.Stack` ou é alguma outra implementação de pilha?

Comment: eu vou por o codigo completo para um entendimento melhor.

Comment: Codigo completo agora

Comment: Respondi com base no código que havia originalmente. Vou atualizar a resposta daqui há pouco considerando o código completo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O procedimento deveria ser mais ou menos assim:

1. Insere o primeiro nó na pilha e marca como visitado.
2. Enquanto houver nós na pilha, desempilha o nó e empilha todos os seus vizinhos que não tiverem sido visitados, marcando-os como visitados.

Note que há uma restrição aí: Apenas nós visitados podem entrar na pilha. Isso significa que o `else if` no final é uma violação dessa restrição. Mais do que isso, ele é uma violação do conceito de pilha, onde você está tentando remover um elemento do meio da pilha ao invés de remover do topo. Aquele `remove` não deveria estar lá.

A classe `java.util.Stack` herda o [método `remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove(int)) de `java.util.Vector`. Este método não faz o que você espera que faria. Ele não vai remover o elemento `topo` da pilha. Ao invés disso, ele vai interpretar `topo` como sendo a posição do elemento a ser removido. Isso vai bagunçar totalmente com a sua pilha.

Inclusive, não é recomendado utilizar-se a classe `java.util.Stack` devido a inúmeras falhas de projeto que ela tem (principalmente por herdar de `Vector`). Veja mais sobre isso [**aqui**](https://keithwilliamstechblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/13/why-the-java-stack-class-is-bad/). O ideal é você implementar a sua própria pilha (vou dar um nome diferente para evitar confusão):

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public interface Pilha<T> {
    public T top() throws NoSuchElementException;
    public T pop() throws NoSuchElementException;
    public void push(T element);
    public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class PilhaArrayList<T> implements Pilha<T> {
    private final List<T> elementos;

    public PilhaArrayList() {
        this.elementos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public T top() throws NoSuchElementException {
         if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
         return elementos.get(elementos.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public T pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
         if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
         return elementos.remove(elementos.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void push(T element) {
        elementos.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return elementos.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Seu código arrumado deve ser assim:

```
    public void pilhaDFS(int s) {
        boolean[] visitados = new boolean[n];
        visitados[s] = true;
        Pilha<Integer> pilha = new PilhaArrayList<>();
        pilha.push(s);
        while (!pilha.isEmpty()) {
            int topo = pilha.pop();
            for (int linha : arestas[s]) {
                if (visitados[linha]) continue;
                System.out.println(s + ">>" + linha);
                visitados[linha] = true;
                pilha.push(linha);
            }
        }
    }
```

Observe que o valor da variável `gatilho` nunca era lido em lugar nenhum, e portanto era inútil. O `break` que acompanhava o `gatilho` era nocivo, pois impedia a sua busca de voltar alguns passos e tentar prosseguir por outro caminho tão logo encontrasse o primeiro "beco sem saída". Inicializar o array `visitados` com tudo `false` é desnecessário pois todo array de `boolean` já é criado com `false` em todas as posições.

Por fim, é boa ideia seguir as [**convenções de código**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132) no que diz respeito a nomenclatura de variáveis.

Olhando para o resto do código, tipos genéricos e arrays não se dão bem juntos. Sugiro modelar as arestas com lista de adjacência:

```
private final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> arestas;
```

O código da sua classe fica assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public Grafo {
    private final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> arestas;
    private final int n;
    private int qtdArestas = 0;

    public Grafo(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        arestas = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void adicionaAresta(int origem, int destino) {
        List<Integer> adjacencias = arestas.get(origem);
        if (adjacencias == null) {
            adjacencias = new ArrayList<>();
            arestas.put(origem, adjacencias);
        }
        adjacencias.add(destino);
        qtdArestas++;
    }

    // Resto da classe.
}
```

O método `pilhaDFS` que mostrei acima ficaria quase igual. A única mudança é que `arestas[s]` viraria `arestas.get(s)`.

Seus métodos `dfs` ficariam assim:

```
    private int dfs(int s, boolean[] visited, int contador) {
        if (visited[s]) return contador;
        contador++;
        visited[s] = true;
        for (int n : arestas.get(s)) {
            System.out.println(s + ">>" + n);
            contador = dfs(n, visited, contador);
        }
        return contador;
    }

    public void dfs(int s) {
        int b = dfs(s, new boolean[n], 0);
        System.out.println(contador);
    }
```

Note que o `dfs` com vários parâmetros é privado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante.

Comment: @AmandaNunes Terminei a resposta. Foi um prazer ajudá-la.

Comment: Amigo, tem uma parte q ta dando erro ainda

Comment: @AmandaNunes Qual é?

Comment: ja consertei, muito obrigado