# Como fazer pra toda vez que passar "true", ele imprimir o objeto instanciado inteiro?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Loja {

    private ArrayList<Produto> ListaDeProdutos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void cadastrarProduto(Produto produto){
        ListaDeProdutos.add(produto);
    }

    public void listarProdutos(){
        ListaDeProdutos.forEach(P -> System.out.println(P.toString() + "\n"));
    }

    public void listarDiscos(){
        ListaDeProdutos.forEach(P -> System.out.println(P.toString().contains("Banda"))); 
        //eu quero que ele imprima todo o conteúdo setado, não apenas "true"
    }
}
```

**Teste**

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loja l1 = new Loja();
        l1.cadastrarProduto(new Livro("Java - Use A cabeça", 01, 120.00f, "Fulano de tal", "DevMasters", 400, "PROGRAMAÇÃO"));
        l1.cadastrarProduto(new Livro("LIVRO DE C", 02, 80.00f, "Deitel", "Dev Masters", 800, "PROGRAMAÇÃO"));
        l1.cadastrarProduto(new Livro("PYTHON", 03, 100.00f, "Lokão dazideia", "Dev Masters", 200, "PROGRAMAÇÃO"));
        l1.cadastrarProduto(new Disco("Back in Black", 04, 100.00f, "AC/DC", "Hard Rock", 15));
        l1.cadastrarProduto(new Disco("Sattelite", 05, 20.00f, "P.O.D.", "White Metal", 11));
        l1.cadastrarProduto(new Disco("Musashi", 06, 15.00f, "Rashid", "Rap", 14));    
        l1.listarDiscos();
    }
}
```

**Saída**

```
false
false
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pergunta não dá muitos detalhes, mas seria algo assim:

```
for (Produto produto : ListaDeProdutos ) {
    if (produto.nome.contains("Banda")) {
        System.out.println(produto.nome);
        System.out.println(produto.preco);
        System.out.println(produto.genero);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/GetMembersToPrint.java).

Achei melhor fazer. O uso de *stream* pode parecer bonitinho, mas é mais lento, tem semântica diferente do laço normal, embora nesse exemplo não cause problemas, mas tem uma série de implicações que quase ninguém entende e o normal é causar problemas, sendo que quase sempre não há ganho real a não ser, em alguns casos, deixar um código com menos linhas, o que nem sempre é bom. Nesse caso isto nem ocorreria de fato, então é pura perda de tempo.

Também [não use o `tostring()` para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), não faz o menor sentido criar algo de lógica geral para atender um requisito específico. É um abuso usá-lo para formatar dados, pior ainda mandar um função de depuração ser usado com complexidade O(n).

Na verdade aí pode ter um erro conceitual. Não sei se `Loja` deveria imprimir alguma coisa, ela processar é ok, imprimir já é um detalhe de plataforma onde roda e talvez deveria ser manipulado em outro lugar. Para exercício pode fazer assim, mas saiba que em código real não é assim que se faz.

Comment: Desculpa pela falta de detalhe, foi a pressa. Mas acha que falta eu descrever mais?

Comment: Eu poderia ter dado uma resposta melhor se tivesse mais informação.

Comment: Sua resposta foi excelente. Desculpa pela inexperiência.

Comment: `public void listarDiscos(){
     for (Produto produto : ListaDeProdutos ) {
         if (produto.toString().contains("Banda")) {
             System.out.println(produto.toString());
         }
     
     }
    }`

Comment: consegui adaptar ao meu problema e deu certo. :)

Comment: Não deu certo, funcionou, certo é outra coisa, você está abusando do `ToString()`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101

Comment: Verdade. Como eu poderia fazer então?

Comment: Como eu fiz....

Answer (score 3):

O método `contains` retorna um `boolean`, por isso o código só imprime `true` ou `false`. Se quer imprimir os produtos que satisfazem uma condição, pode fazer um `for` simples [como sugeriu o Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/329565/112052).

Outra opção é transformar a lista em um *stream* e usar `filter` para filtrar os produtos que satisfazem a sua condição e em seguida imprimi-los:

```
ListaDeProdutos.stream()
    // filtrar produtos
    .filter(p -> p.toString().contains("Banda"))
    // imprimir
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Mas se você quer filtrar os produtos por um tipo específico (no caso, `Disco`), poderia usar `instanceof` para testar se o produto é uma instância de `Disco`:

```
ListaDeProdutos.stream()
    // filtrar produtos que são Disco
    .filter(p -> p instanceof Disco)
    // imprimir
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu queria. Muito obrigado. Assim eu não abuso do `toString()`

Comment: @EmersonAraujo neste caso está abusando do `toString()` e de *streams*.

Comment: eu ainda estou começado a entender sobre **POO** e **Java**, desculpe se eu estou errando muito.

Comment: @EmersonAraujo De fato, o melhor é usar atributos da classe (como o nome, tipo, etc) para verificar o que ela representa, em vez de `toString()`. Outra dica é ler as [convenções de código](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/codeconventions-135099.html) - nomes de variáveis, por exemplo, devem começam com letra minúscula, então seria melhor ter `listaDeProdutos` (com `l` minúsculo). Com `L` maiúsculo fica parecendo nome de classe e pode confundir outros já acostumados com tais convenções - veja mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/112052

Comment: Vou ler sim, obrigado pelas dicas.