# Java retornando 0 em multiplicação

Tags: java

O codigo é até simples fazer o calculo do rendimento de um vendedor porem na multiplicação no caso de 150000 * 0,1 ele retorna 0

codigo /

```js
public class FuncionarioComissionado {
//Strings private para poder usar Get/Set
//Atributos
private String nome;
private String CPF;
private double taxaComissao;
private double vendasBrutas;
private double rendimentos;


// Criação de um construtor para a classe FuncionarioComissionado
// Construtor
public FuncionarioComissionado(String nome, String CPF, double taxaComissao, double vendasBrutas) {
 this.nome = nome;
 this.CPF = CPF;
 this.taxaComissao = taxaComissao;
 this.vendasBrutas = vendasBrutas;
}
// Calculo dos Rendimentos
//Metodo
private void Rendimentos(){
 rendimentos = (vendasBrutas * (taxaComissao / 100));
}

// Criação de Get's para cada Atributo
// Metodos
public double getRendimentos() {
 return rendimentos;
}
public String getNome() {
 return nome;
}
public String getCPF() {
 return CPF;
}
public double getTaxaComissao() {
 return taxaComissao / 100;
}
public double getVendasBrutas() {
 return vendasBrutas;
}
}
```

teste /

```
FuncionarioComissionado f1 = new FuncionarioComissionado("Guilherme", "12345678921",10,125000);
    System.out.println(f1.getNome());
    System.out.println(f1.getCPF());
    System.out.println(f1.getTaxaComissao());
    System.out.println(f1.getVendasBrutas());
    System.out.println(f1.getRendimentos());
```

Comment: Em que ponto o erro ocorre?

Comment: tentando descobrir mas o erro seria o getRendimentos retornando 0 ao invés de (125000 * 0,1)

Comment: Voce nao está calculando rendimentos, só está retornando um valor vazio da variavel.

Comment: Esta conta nunca chega a ocorrer, pq vc simplesmente nao a efetua.

Comment: Isso não efetuaria a conta?
private void Rendimentos(){
 rendimentos = (vendasBrutas * (taxaComissao / 100));

Comment: Releia meus 2 ultimos comentarios novamente.

Comment: ah ! Facepalm, eu não invoquei o metodo T_T

Comment: Bom na classe filho funcionou mas neste mesmo invocando metodo retornou 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retorna 0 porque seu método `getRendimentos()` está simplesmente retornando o valor de inicialização da variável `rendimentos`, em momento algum do código você efetua cálculo.

Sugiro duas modificações no código:

- não inicie nome de métodos com letra maiúscula, a [convenção do java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153540/at%C3%A9-que-ponto-devo-seguir-as-conven%C3%A7%C3%B5es-onde-posso-aplicar-espec%C3%ADficos-padr%C3%B5es) pede que somente o nome do construtor possa ser maiúsculo, e os demais métodos seguem o formato camelcase;
- se precisa armazenar os rendimentos a parte, primeiro chame o método que calcula e depois chame o getter dele.

Com essas alteraçoes, a classe fica desta forma:

```
class FuncionarioComissionado {
    //Strings private para poder usar Get/Set
    //Atributos
    private String nome;
    private String CPF;
    private double taxaComissao;
    private double vendasBrutas;
    private double rendimentos;


    // Criação de um construtor para a classe FuncionarioComissionado
    // Construtor
    public FuncionarioComissionado(String nome, String CPF, double taxaComissao, double vendasBrutas) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.CPF = CPF;
        this.taxaComissao = taxaComissao;
        this.vendasBrutas = vendasBrutas;
    }

    // Calculo dos Rendimentos
    //Metodo
    public void calculaRendimentos(){
        rendimentos = (vendasBrutas * (taxaComissao / 100));
    }

    // Criação de Get's para cada Atributo
    // Metodos
    public double getRendimentos() {
        return rendimentos;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public String getCPF() {
        return CPF;
    }
    public double getTaxaComissao() {
        return taxaComissao / 100;
    }
    public double getVendasBrutas() {
        return vendasBrutas;
    }
}
```

O teste:

```
class Teste {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    FuncionarioComissionado f1 = new FuncionarioComissionado("Guilherme", "12345678921",10,125000);
    System.out.println(f1.getNome());
    System.out.println(f1.getCPF());
    System.out.println(f1.getTaxaComissao());
    System.out.println(f1.getVendasBrutas());
    f1.calculaRendimentos();
    System.out.println(f1.getRendimentos());

    }
}
```

Veja em funcionamento no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/Dm2Rt3)

Comment: Obrigado eu entendi o que tava faltando com a ajuda do seus comentarios, porém errei na construção do codigo, faltou os () em f1.calculaRendimentos();

Comment: Melhor ainda seria calcular os rendimentos no construtor, pois não há razão para deixar isso para depois quando um método específico for chamado.

Comment: Ideal seria mas não sei como fazer isto >.<

Comment: @guilhermecabrals Basta colocar a linha `rendimentos = (vendasBrutas * (taxaComissao / 100));` no final do construtor e então você pode deletar o método `calculaRendimentos` (ou `Rendimentos` de acordo com seu código original) e todas as chamadas a ele.