# Executar select da classe DAO em java

Tags: java, jdbc, padrão-dao

Pessoal estou com problemas para usar um select de uma classe dao em uma classe main.
Podem me ajudar.
Segue código.

```
package Model;

public class MTotalProduto {

    private String codigoBarra;
    private double totalProduto;
    private int produto_id;

    public MTotalProduto() {
    }

    public MTotalProduto(String codigoBarra, double totalProduto, int produto_id) {
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
        this.totalProduto = totalProduto;
        this.produto_id = produto_id;
    }

    public String getCodigoBarra() {
        return codigoBarra;
    }

    public void setCodigoBarra(String codigoBarra) {
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
    }

    public double getTotalProduto() {
        return totalProduto;
    }

    public void setTotalProduto(double totalProduto) {
        this.totalProduto = totalProduto;
    }

    public int getProduto_id() {
        return produto_id;
    }

    public void setProduto_id(int produto_id) {
        this.produto_id = produto_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MTotalProduto{" + "codigoBarra=" + codigoBarra + ", totalProduto=" + totalProduto + ", produto_id=" + produto_id + '}';
    }

}
```

```
package DAO;

import Model.MTotalProduto;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DTotalProduto {

    private Connection con;

    public DTotalProduto(Connection con) {

        setCon(con);

    }

    public Connection getCon() {

        return con;

    }

    public void setCon(Connection con) {

        this.con = con;
    }

    public String salvar(MTotalProduto tot) {

        String sql = "insert into estoque.total_produto values(?,?,?)";

        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, tot.getCodigoBarra());
            ps.setDouble(2, tot.getTotalProduto());
            ps.setInt(3, tot.getProduto_id());

            if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {

                return "Total Salvo com sucesso!";

            } else {

                return "Erro ao Salvar Total de Produtos!";

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            return e.getMessage();

        }

    }

    public String totProduto(MTotalProduto mt) {

        String sql = "SELECT total FROM estoque.total_produto "
                + "where produto_id=?";

        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, mt.getProduto_id());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {

                    MTotalProduto mtp = new MTotalProduto();
                    mtp.setTotalProduto(rs.getDouble("total"));
                    mtp.setProduto_id(rs.getInt("produto_id"));

            } else {

                return "Erro ao Carregar Total de Produtos!";

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            return "Exeção ao carregar Total de Produtos!";

        }

        return "Total não carregado";

    }

}
```

```
package Principal;

import DAO.DConexao;
import DAO.DTotalProduto;
import Model.MTotalProduto;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class TotalProdutoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = DConexao.abrirConexao();
        DTotalProduto dtp = new DTotalProduto(con);
        MTotalProduto tp = new MTotalProduto();


    }

}
```

A intenção é setar um `produto_id` e mostrar o valor total.

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, nomes de pacotes devem ter todas as letras em minúsculas e nomes de identificadores devem seguir o padrão camelCase. Veja mais [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132) sobre as convenções. Além disso, os nomes das classes devem ser descritivos, e portanto é bom evitar abreviações obscuras, como no caso dos seus prefixos `M` e `D`. Chame suas classes de `Conexao`, de `TotalProduto` e de `TotalProdutoDAO` e use `produtoId` ao invés de `produto_id`.

Em seguida, classes imutáveis são bem mais fáceis de se utilizar, de se reutilizar, de se testar e são muito menos propensas a causar bugs inesperados. Assim sendo, sugiro que a classe `TotalProduto` seja imutável. Prefira fazer classes imutáveis quando possível e só introduza a mutabilidade quando houver uma razão boa e forte para tal. Sua classe `TotalProduto` fica assim:

```
package model;

public final class TotalProduto {

    private final String codigoBarra;
    private final double totalProduto;
    private final int produtoId;

    public TotalProduto(String codigoBarra, double totalProduto, int produtoId) {
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
        this.totalProduto = totalProduto;
        this.produtoId = produtoId;
    }

    public String getCodigoBarra() {
        return codigoBarra;
    }

    public double getTotalProduto() {
        return totalProduto;
    }

    public int getProdutoId() {
        return produtoId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TotalProduto{" +
                "codigoBarra=" + codigoBarra +
                ", totalProduto=" + totalProduto +
                ", produtoId=" + produtoId + '}';
    }
}
```

O retorno de um método deve servir para informar o resultado esperado. No seu método `totProduto` (que deveria se chamar `totalProduto`), o retorno deveria informar o total do produto. Entretanto, nos seus métodos, você usurpou o `return` para mostrar mensagens de erro ou de sucesso.

Imagine, por exemplo que eu quisesse fazer uma função que soma dois números:

```
 public String somar(int a, int b) {
     int r = a + b;
     return "Somado com sucesso.";
 }
```

Agora, imagine que eu vá usar esse método para fazer `somar(16, 28)`. A resposta que eu gostaria de ter é 44, mas ao invés disso, eu tenho como resultado uma string praticamente inútil. Para resolver esse tipo de coisa, basta eu abolir essa prática de retornar strings com códigos ou mensagens de status:

```
 public int somar(int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
 }
```

Quanto aos casos onde ocorre um exceção, o que você deve fazer é simplesmente lançar essas exceções. As exceções foram inventadas exatamente para sinalizar condições de erros. Assim sendo, ao retornar strings com mensagens de erro, você está subvertendo o mecanismo de tratamento de exceções que já existe e que foi inventado justamente para livrar o programador de ter que usurpar o retorno das funções/métodos com códigos e/ou mensagens de erro.

Seu código deveria utilizar o *try-with-resources*. Sugiro a você ler todo o conteúdo [**desta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) para entender o porquê. Veja também que essa pergunta mostra muito de como você deveria lidar para construir o seu DAO.

Ah, e lembre-se de **sempre** utilizar o `Connection`, o `PreparedStatement` e o `ResultSet` com o *try-with-resources*.

Seu código do `TotalProdutoDAO` deve ficar assim:

```
package dao;

import model.TotalProduto;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TotalProdutoDAO {

    private static final String INSERT_SQL =
            "INSERT INTO estoque.total_produto VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String SELECT_SQL =
            "SELECT total FROM estoque.total_produto WHERE produto_id = ?";

    private final Connection con;

    public TotalProdutoDAO(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    public void salvar(TotalProduto tot) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL)) {
            ps.setString(1, tot.getCodigoBarra());
            ps.setDouble(2, tot.getTotalProduto());
            ps.setInt(3, tot.getProdutoId());

            if (ps.executeUpdate() == 0) {
                throw new SQLException("Nenhum resultado foi produzido.");
            }
        }
    }

    public double totalProduto(int idProduto) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL)) {
            ps.setInt(1, idProduto);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (!rs.next()) {
                    throw new SQLException("Nenhum resultado foi produzido.");
                }
                return rs.getDouble("total");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que o método `totalProduto` não trabalha com o objeto `TotalProduto` porque ele só lida com os campos `idProduto` e `total`, deixando o `codigoBarra` de lado. Se você vai usar uma classe que modela uma tabela do banco de dados, é boa ideia ou utilizar todos os seus campos ou simplesmente não utilizá-la. Qualquer meio-termo provavelmente é uma má prática de programação. Aqui no caso, esse método só traz um `double` como resultado a partir de um `int`.

Se a sua ideia era trazer instâncias de `MTotalProduto`, então faça esse método assim (modificando também a instrução SQL):

```
    private static final String SELECT_SQL =
            "SELECT total, codigo_barra FROM estoque.total_produto WHERE produto_id = ?";

    public TotalProduto buscar(int idProduto) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL)) {
            ps.setInt(1, idProduto);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (!rs.next()) {
                    throw new SQLException("Nenhum resultado foi produzido.");
                }
                double total = rs.getDouble("total");
                String codigoBarra = rs.getDouble("codigo_barra");
                return new TotalProduto(codigoBarra, total, idProduto);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sua classe principal está muito pouco desenvolvida e não há contexto suficiente na sua pergunta para saber o que ela viraria. No entanto, aqui vai um exemplo de alguma coisa:

```
package principal;

import dao.Conexao;
import dao.TotalProdutoDAO;
import model.TotalProduto;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TotalProdutoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // Lê o id do produto desejado.
        int produtoId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // Cria e usa o DAO.
        double total;
        try (Connection con = Conexao.abrirConexao()) {
            TotalProdutoDao dao = new TotalProdutoDAO(con);
            total = dao.totalProduto(produtoId);
        }

        // Mostra o resultado.
        System.out.println(total);        
    }    
}
```

Observe que tive que colocar o gerenciamento da conexão no `main`. Isso não é bom, mas sem saber mais sobre o contexto onde o `TotalProdutoDAO` será usado e nem saber o que existe no código de sua classe `DConexao`, é o que dá para fazer por enquanto. Também não há contexto o suficiente para saber qual seria a melhor forma de tratar a `SQLException`, mas seja lá qual for, definitivamente não era do jeito que você estava fazendo.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema. Segue o código.

```
package Model;

public class MTotalProduto {

    private String codigoBarra;
    private double totalProduto;
    private int produtoId;

    public MTotalProduto() {
    }

    public MTotalProduto(String codigoBarra, double totalProduto, int produtoId) {
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
        this.totalProduto = totalProduto;
        this.produtoId = produtoId;
    }

    public String getCodigoBarra() {
        return codigoBarra;
    }

    public void setCodigoBarra(String codigoBarra) {
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
    }

    public double getTotalProduto() {
        return totalProduto;
    }

    public void setTotalProduto(double totalProduto) {
        this.totalProduto = totalProduto;
    }

    public int getProdutoId() {
        return produtoId;
    }

    public void setProdutoId(int produtoId) {
        this.produtoId = produtoId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MTotalProduto{" + "codigoBarra=" + codigoBarra + ", totalProduto=" + totalProduto + ", produtoId=" + produtoId + '}';
    }

}

package DAO;

import Model.MTotalProduto;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DTotalProduto {

    private Connection con;

    public DTotalProduto(Connection con) {

        setCon(con);

    }

    public Connection getCon() {

        return con;

    }

    public void setCon(Connection con) {

        this.con = con;
    }

    public String salvar(MTotalProduto tot) {

        String sql = "insert into estoque.total_produto values(?,?,?)";

        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, tot.getCodigoBarra());
            ps.setDouble(2, tot.getTotalProduto());
            ps.setInt(3, tot.getProdutoId());

            if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {

                return "Total Salvo com sucesso!";

            } else {

                return "Erro ao Salvar Total de Produtos!";

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            return e.getMessage();

        }

    }

    public void totalProduto(MTotalProduto tp) {

        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement("SELECT total FROM estoque.total_produto where produto_id = ?");

            ps.setInt(1, tp.getProdutoId());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                tp.setTotalProduto(rs.getDouble("total"));

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}


package Principal;

import DAO.DConexao;
import DAO.DTotalProduto;
import Model.MTotalProduto;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class TotalProdutoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = DConexao.abrirConexao();
        MTotalProduto tp = new MTotalProduto();
        DTotalProduto dtp = new DTotalProduto(con);

       tp.setProdutoId(1);
       dtp.totalProduto(tp);
       tp.setTotalProduto(tp.getTotalProduto() + 1);

        System.out.println(tp);

    }

}
```