# Função .filter() para um List<Class>

Tags: java, android, stream

Eu tenho uma classe `Pessoa` que tem as colunas `Integer id`. `String name`, e `String date_born`.

Na minha activity principal eu já estou recuperando a lista de pessoas que vem da minha requisição feita na API e já mando para minha função para agrupar.

```
private void loadList(List<Pessoas> listPessoas){
       Map<String, List<Pessoas>> listMap = listPessoas.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pessoa::getDate_born)); //LISTA AGRUPADA
}
```

Mas eu preciso filtrar a lista antes de poder agrupar pelo campo `date_born`, aí vai minha pergunta.

```
private void loadList(List<Pessoas> listPessoas){
      List<Pessoas> listPessoasFiltered = ??           
      Map<String, List<Pessoas>> listMap = listPessoasFiltered.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pessoa::getDate_born));
}
```

Já existe uma função tipo `.filter()` que retorna a lista ou tem que implementar uma função de filtro para retornar minha lista de pessoas filtrada antes de agrupar as pessoas por este campo?

**Lembrando não é dentro de um Adapter é um filtro de uma lista.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa criar uma outra lista filtrada, pode aproveitar que está usando *streams* e usar o [método `filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Map<String, List<Pessoa>> map = listPessoas.stream()
    // filtrar pelo critério que precisa
    .filter(pessoa -> pessoa.getName().endsWith("o"))
    // agrupar por data de nascimento
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pessoa::getDate_born));
```

No exemplo acima, estou filtrando os nomes que terminam em "o", mas você pode usar qualquer critério que desejar (o importante é que o *lambda* passado para `filter` retorne `true` para os elementos que você quer manter).

---

Lembrando ainda que `getDate_born` não está de acordo com as [convenções de nomenclatura da linguagem](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) (deveria ser algo como `getDateBorn`, por exemplo). Ver mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/112052).

Comment: To chorando de felicidade, achei que ia precisar criar uma função pra isso , agora que vi que tem uma pronta é só usar vlw mesmo.