# Como verificar se minha entrada é número ou texto?

Tags: java, scanner

Gostaria de saber como posso verificar o tipo do valor que entra no meu `Scanner`, para retornar pro usuário que aquela entrada só recebe número e que ele digitou um texto ou caractere.

```
public class WhileChallenge {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double grades = 0.0;
        double grades_total = 0.0;
        int grades_amount = 0;
        
        Scanner input_value = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(grades != -1)
        {
            System.out.println("Insert a grade:");
            grades = Double.parseDouble(input_value.next().replace(",", "."));
            
            if(grades < 0.0 || grades > 10.0)
            {
                System.out.println("Out of range value");
            }else if(grades >= 0.0 && grades <= 10.0)
            {
                grades_total += grades;
                grades_amount++;
            }
            //Se a nota for diferente de um número; Pede pro usuário digitar um número
        }
        
        System.out.println("Average: " + ((grades_total)/grades_amount));
        
        input_value.close();    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sobre sua outra dúvida (que retirei porque não tem a ver com o problema de programação da pergunta), o site aplica o *syntax highlight* de acordo com as tags da pergunta, e como já tem a tag [tag:java], será aplicada a sintaxe correta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)), `Double.parseDouble` lança uma exceção (um [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)) se a string não tiver um número válido. Então basta capturar esta exceção para saber se deu errado:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double gradesTotal = 0;
double gradesAmount = 0;
while (true) {
    double grade;
    System.out.println("Insert a grade:");
    while (true) { // enquanto não digitar um número válido, continua no while
        try {
            grade = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine().replace(",", "."));
            break; // se chegou aqui é porque o número é válido, então posso sair do while
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // número inválido
            System.out.println("Digite um número válido");
        }
    }

    // se for -1, sai do while mais externo
    if (grade == -1)
        break;

    if (grade < 0.0 || grade > 10.0) {
        System.out.println("Out of range value");
    } else {
        gradesTotal += grade;
        gradesAmount++;
    }
}
```

Repare que fiz um `while(true)` externo (para ficar repetindo tudo, até encontrar um `-1`, que é a condição de saída que você colocou), e outro mais interno só para ler o número (e ele fica pedindo que digite novamente, até que o número seja válido).

Veja também que no `else` não precisa testar todas as condições de novo. Se o número estiver entre 0 e 10 ele não entrará no `if`, então se chegou no `else` é porque com certeza ele não é menor que zero e nem maior que 10, então testar isso de novo é redundante e desnecessário.

Também mudei os nomes das variáveis para deixar de acordo com as [convenções do Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), que prefere `nomesAssim` em vez de `nomes_assim`.

Comment: Quando você fala de preferir nomes assim:  `nomesAssim` em vez de `nomes_assim`, implica em que ? Acabei de dar uma lida na documentação  e ele só diz: 
"Nomes de variáveis ​​não devem começar com caracteres de sublinhado _ ou cifrão $, embora ambos sejam permitidos."

Quando eu insiro um:   _   entre as palavras da var, quais são as consequências ?

Comment: @MatheusLuis São apenas convenções. Se vc seguir ou não, o código vai continuar compilando e funcionando sem problemas, não vai dar erro. Convenções são apenas definições arbitrárias, mas que podem ser úteis se forem seguidas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions#Software_maintenance

Comment: @MatheusLuis E o link que passei diz: "*mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters*" - ou seja, começa com minúscula e palavras internas começam com maiúscula - mas como eu disse, são convenções, não existe obrigação de seguir, embora haja vantagens em fazê-lo. Veja mais sobre o assunto aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/112052

Comment: @MatheusLuis Só pra terminar, um trecho que acho interessante (do link que passei acima): "*Por fim, a escolha das convenções a seguir fica a seu critério no fim das contas. No caso da nomenclatura de identificadores, vejo pouco motivo para fugir da convenção vez que, embora ela de fato poderia ter sido melhor, você já vai estar utilizando um monte de classes e métodos de bibliotecas que seguem a convenção padrão (até mesmo os do pacote java.lang), o que significa que ao tentar ir contra isso, você acabaria criando um código com um estilo heterogêneo e despadronizado*"